# Draw a unicorn in TikZ 

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

I'm currently reading [Sparks of Artificial General Intelligence: Early experiments with GPT-4](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.12712.pdf). This paper by Microsoft employees experiments with the capabilities of GPT-4, a successor of ChatGPT. One task is to draw a unicorn with tikz.ㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤㅤ

They claim:

> GPT-4 produces impressive outputs that are [...] at least comparable (if not superior) to what a human would do.

Who wants to prove them wrong?

edit: Please don't include PNG / JPG / other pixel image formats. MS-SPO is the only one allowed to do that (as a grandfathering-rule) - kudos for finding the loophole in this question and for thinking outside of the box

edit: We now have 200 [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) questions!

Comment: Do you consider vector formats to be an image format?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I've edited to "pixel image" - vector images are fine :-)

Comment: Yes, this is a really fun question! seeing all those packages with predefined unicorns made me laugh.

Comment: I got some bad and no good results from ChatGPT. Some might find them funny (does this qualify them because of the "fun" tag?) but I guess no one cares for them. –

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{pgf-spectra}
\pgfspectrashade[v](380,780){myShadeC}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[shading=myShadeC]
 \duck[body=pink]
 \shade[shading angle=45] \duckpathlonghair;
 \duck[invisible,body=pink,unicorn=magenta!60!violet]
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I love it  And it's already way better than any of the GPT-4 examples 

Comment: @MartinThoma :)

Comment: You do realise this code is already being used to train ChatGPT to generate unicorns, and based on the "is already way better" comment, in a few days all of the internet will be baffled by how all of the sudden all unicorns began showing duck-y traits in their physical appearance

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik ... that's part of the plan for duck world domination :)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik, just a thought: if AI is what it pretends to be … why does it need our human input? (Please try thinking in terms, which remove all humanized terms, like „learning“, „being or doing sth intelligent“ etc. to perceive the technology as it is.)

Comment: @MS-SPO Well, in our specific example of drawing a unicorn in TikZ... any kind of intelligence, whether human, artificial, alien, or supernatural, would need human input just to know what "unicorn" and "TikZ" are, no?

Comment: Please see 3 comments above, that‘s what I refer to: „unicorns“ are already known, and yet the machine needs more human input to excel human ideas … Let‘s wait for results: I don‘t expect much. // And again, „knowing“ is a human property. Just to remind you of an effective trap for our perception. // For discussions somebody should open a chat, BTW.

Answer (score 51):

Well, a little late for the party but, ladies and gentlemen let me introduce you my unicorn, Clavileño, my faithful companion for all these years:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{3d,perspective}

\colorlet{brownxy}{brown!40!red}
\colorlet{brownxz}{brown!65!red}
\colorlet{brownyz}{brown!90!red}

\tikzset
{%
   declare function={
     rh=4*(1-cos(30)); % runner height
     },
   xy/.style={canvas is xy plane at z=#1},
   xz/.style={canvas is xz plane at y=#1},
   yz/.style={canvas is yz plane at x=#1},
   pics/runner/.style={
     code={%
       \draw[xz=0 ,fill=brownxz] (0,4) ++ (240:4) arc (240:300:4) -- cycle;
       \draw[xy=rh,fill=brownxy] (2,0) rectangle (-2,-0.2);
      }},
   pics/leg/.style={
     code={%
       \path[xz=0]                 (0,0) --++ (0,1.5) arc (0:135:0.15) coordinate (aux) ;
       \draw[xz=-0.4,fill=brownyz] (0,0) --++ (0,1.5) arc (0:135:0.15) -- (aux) arc (135:0:0.15) --++ (0,-1.5) -- cycle;
       \draw[xz=0,fill=brownxz]    (0,0) --++ (0,1.5) arc (0:180:0.15) |- cycle;
       \fill[fill opacity=0.5]   (0,0,0) --++ (-0.3,0,0) --++ (0,0,0.2) --++ (0.3,0,0) --++ (0,-0.4,0) --++ (0,0,-0.2) -- cycle;
       \draw (0,-0.2,0) --++ (0,0,0.2);
       \foreach\i in {-0.1,-0.2}
         \fill[xz=0,black] (\i,1.5) circle (0.2mm);
     }},
   pics/body/.style={
     code={%
       \draw[xz=0,pic actions] (-1.3,1.5) coordinate (-A) --++ (2.6,0)       coordinate (-B) --++
                               (70:1.2)   coordinate (-C) arc  (160:60:0.2)  coordinate (-D) --++
                               (-30:0.6)  coordinate (-E) arc  (240:390:0.3) coordinate (-F) --++
                               (120:1.2)  coordinate (-G) arc  (30:140:0.5)  coordinate (-H) --++
                               (230:1.5)  coordinate (-I) arc  (-40:-90:0.2) coordinate (-J) --++
                               (-1.9,0)   coordinate (-K) |- cycle;
       % mouth
       \fill[xz,black,fill opacity=0.5] (-E) ++ (60:0.3) coordinate (aux) circle (0.3);
       \draw[xz]               (aux) --++ (10:0.3);
       % eye
       \fill[xz=0,black]       (2.1,3.5) circle (0.1);
     }},
   pics/ear/.style={
     code={%
       \draw[xz=0,rotate=-15,pic actions] (0,0) -- (240:0.4) arc (150:390:0.2) -- cycle;
     }},
}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,isometric view,rotate around z=180]
% runners
\pic at (0,-0.8,0) {runner};
\foreach\i in {1.3,-1}
{
  \draw[xy=rh,fill=brownxy] (\i,0.8) rectangle++ (-0.3,-1.6);
  \draw[yz=\i,fill=brownyz] (0.8,rh) rectangle++ (-1.6,-0.2);
}
\pic at (0,1,0) {runner};
\node[xz=1,anchor=south,yshift=.5mm,xscale=-1,fill=none,text=yellow] at (0,0) {\bfseries Clavileño};
\foreach\i in {1.1,1.2,-1.1,-1.2}
  \fill[xz=1,fill=black] (\i,rh-0.1) circle (0.2mm);
% legs
\pic at (1.3,-0.4,rh) {leg};
\pic at (-1 ,-0.4,rh) {leg};
% body coordinates
\pic[fill=none,draw=none] (back)  at (0,-0.4,0) {body};
\pic[fill=none,draw=none] (front) at (0, 0.4,0) {body};
% tail
\path (front-K) -- (back-K) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux);
\draw[xz,xscale=-1,shift={(aux)},fill=brownxz]
   (0,-0.2) to[out=10,in=180]  (0.5,0) to[out=0,in=140] (1,-2)
            to[out=200,in=270] (0.3,-0.8) arc(0:90:0.3) -- cycle;
% saddle
\draw[xy=0,fill=brownxy] (back-K) ++ (2,0) -- (back-K) -- (front-K) -| cycle;
\path (front-K) ++ (0.5,0,0) coordinate (aux1) --++ (0.1,0,0) coordinate (aux2);
\path[yz=0] (aux2) arc (0:135:0.4) coordinate (aux3);
\draw[fill=gray!70!black] (aux2) {[yz=0] arc (0:180:0.4)} {[xy=0] arc (-90:90:0.8 and 0.4)};
\draw (aux2) --++ (0,-0.8,0);
\draw[yz=0,fill=gray] (aux1) arc (0:135:0.4) -- (aux3)  arc (135:0:0.4) -- cycle;
% body and ears
\path[xz=0,fill=none] (front-G) arc (30:135:0.5)  coordinate (aux1);
\path[xz=0,fill=none] (front-F) arc (390:315:0.3) coordinate (aux2);
\path (back-B) -- (back-C) coordinate[pos=1.1]  (aux3);
\pic[fill=brown!30!orange] at (2.2,-0.4,4.4)    {ear};
\draw[fill=brown] (front-B) --++ (0,-0.8,0)  -- (aux3) --++ (0,0.8,0) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=brown!70!red] (aux1) --++ (0,-0.8,0) {[xz=0] arc (135:30:0.5) -- (back-F) arc (390:315:0.3) -- (aux2)} -- cycle;
\pic[fill=brownxz]         at (0,0.4,0)      {body};
\pic[fill=brown!30!orange] at (2.2,0.4,4.4)  {ear};
\pic[draw=none,fill=black!60!brown,scale=0.6] at (2.15,0.4,4.25) {ear};
% more legs
\pic at (1.3,0.8,rh) {leg};
\pic at (-1,0.8 ,rh) {leg};
% handle
\path[xz=0.4,draw=red] (1.4,3.5) coordinate (aux1) ++ (135:0.1) coordinate (aux2) arc (135:-45:0.1) coordinate (aux3);
\path (aux3) --++ (0,0.4,0) coordinate (aux4);
\path (aux1) --++ (0,0.4,0) coordinate (aux5);
\draw[fill=gray,xz=0.4] (aux1) circle (0.15);
\draw[fill=gray!50!black,xz=0] (aux2) arc (135:-45:.1) -- (aux4) arc (-45:135:0.1) -- cycle;
\draw[xz=0,fill=gray] (aux5) circle (0.1);
% unicorn
\path (front-F) -- (back-G) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux);
\draw[shift={(aux)},rotate around y=60,fill=yellow] (4:0.1) arc (4:190:0.1) -- (0,0,1) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:** Here you can see him galloping without fear.
[image]

Comment: Great :) Take that too, AI … ;-)

Comment: A unicorn whose mother is a a wooden horse.

Comment: How do you get the movement/animation, both in code and as post here?

Comment: @MS-SPO, I use the `animate` package and wrap all the picture inside a `scope[rotate around y=\i]` with `\i` between -5 and 5 degrees. This will create a pdf with the frames, that then I convert to gif with ImageMagick (there are many options online too).

Comment: Thank you @JuanCastaño :)

Answer (score 33):

Clearly use of tikz is sign of mere automation.

Discerning artists use latex picture mode for
[planes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114847/1090)
or
[donkeys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312625/1090)
or unicorns which are horned donkeys

```
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.00083333in}
\usepackage{epic}
\begin{document}

\begin{picture}(4974,3714)(0,-10)
\drawline(2037,1362)(1962,12)(2112,1362)
\drawline(1887,2412)(4437,2412)(4437,1437)
    (1887,1437)(837,2262)(462,1812)
    (12,2187)(687,3012)(837,3687)
    (837,3087)(1812,2412)
\drawline(1887,1437)(1512,12)(1962,1437)
\put(687,2637){\circle{150}}
\drawline(4362,1437)(4287,162)(4287,1437)
\drawline(4137,1437)(3987,162)(3987,1437)
\drawline(4437,2412)(4962,1587)
\drawline(580,2900)(-200,3300)(660,3010)
\end{picture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's the kind of unicorn I drew as a child after I got my first "Geodreieck"

Comment: "horned donkeys" made me lol

Answer (score 32):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ducksay}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\ducksay[unicorn]{I'm an unicorn}};
\end{tikzpicture}   
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice package :)

Comment: @MS-SPO Indeed! @ Skillmon did a great job with it!

Answer (score 25):

Merger of MS-SPO's [nice idea](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681460/47927) and an [older answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656691/47927) of mine:

```
\documentclass[border=10Mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% Original Image: Hszone/Wirestock Creators / stock.adobe.com
% https://stock.adobe.com/de/images/unicorn-pixel-art-vector/501392488
\begin{filecontents}{image.dat} 
.2 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  .2 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  .2 .2 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  .2 .2 .2 0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  .2 .2 .2 .2 0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  .2 .2 .2 .2 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  .2 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8  0 0  0  0
0  0  .8 0  .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0
0  0  0  .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 0
0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 .8
0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
.5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
.5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  .5 .5 .5 .5 0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
.5 0  0  0  0  0  .5 .5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
0  .5 .5 .5 .5 .5 0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 0  0  .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 0  0  0  .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 0  0  0  0  .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .6 .6 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{image.dat}{\pixeldata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\pixeldata}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\datacols}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\pixeldata}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\datarows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\datarows} {
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\datacols} {
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{\j}\of{\pixeldata}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pixelvalue}{\pgfplotsretval*100}
        \fill[black!\pixelvalue] (\j,-\i) rectangle +(1,1);
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Let's add some sprinkle of [Sebastiano's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681448/47927) to it:

```
\documentclass[border=10Mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{emoji}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% Original Image: Hszone/Wirestock Creators / stock.adobe.com
% https://stock.adobe.com/de/images/unicorn-pixel-art-vector/501392488
\begin{filecontents}{image.dat} 
.2 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  .2 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  .2 .2 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  .2 .2 .2 0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  .2 .2 .2 .2 0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  .2 .2 .2 .2 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  .2 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8  0 0  0  0
0  0  .8 0  .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0
0  0  0  .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 0
0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 .8
0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
.5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
.5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  .5 .5 .5 .5 0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
.5 0  0  0  0  0  .5 .5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
0  .5 .5 .5 .5 .5 0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 0  0  .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 0  0  0  .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 0  0  0  0  .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .6 .6 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{image.dat}{\pixeldata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.33cm, y=0.33cm]

\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\pixeldata}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\datacols}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\pixeldata}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\datarows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\datarows} {
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\datacols} {
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{\j}\of{\pixeldata}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pixelvalue}{\pgfplotsretval}
        \ifdim\pixelvalue pt>0pt\relax
            \node[scale=\pixelvalue] at (\j,-\i) {\emoji{unicorn}};
        \fi
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Variation with mirrored "eye pixel":

```
\documentclass[border=10Mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{emoji}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

% Original Image: Hszone/Wirestock Creators / stock.adobe.com
% https://stock.adobe.com/de/images/unicorn-pixel-art-vector/501392488
\begin{filecontents}{image.dat} 
.2 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  .2 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  .2 .2 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  .2 .2 .2 0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  .2 .2 .2 .2 0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  .2 .2 .2 .2 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  .2 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8  0 0  0  0
0  0  .8 0  .8 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0  0
0  0  0  .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 0
0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8 .8
0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
.5 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
.5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  .5 .5 .5 .5 0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
.5 0  0  0  0  0  .5 .5 0  .5 0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
0  .5 .5 .5 .5 .5 0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 .8
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .5 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .6 .8 .8 0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 .6 0  0  .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .4 .6 .6 0  0  0  .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .4 .4 .6 .6 0  0  0  0  .8 0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  .6 .6 0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread{image.dat}{\pixeldata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.33cm, y=0.33cm]

\pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\pixeldata}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\datacols}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\pixeldata}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\datarows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\datarows} {
    \foreach \j in {0,...,\datacols} {
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{\j}\of{\pixeldata}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pixelvalue}{\pgfplotsretval}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\pixelmirror}{(\i == 11 && \j == 7 ? 1 : 0)}
        \ifdim\pixelvalue pt>0pt\relax
            \ifnum\pixelmirror=1\relax
                \node[xscale=-\pixelvalue, yscale=\pixelvalue] 
                    at (\j,-\i) {\emoji{unicorn}};
            \else
                \node[scale=\pixelvalue] 
                    at (\j,-\i) {\emoji{unicorn}};
            \fi
        \fi
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Accoding to the licence, it take it that it is allowed to use the original file like this. If I misread the terms or if they changed, please notify me. If somebody has some nice similar pixel art that is in the Public Domain, let me know.

Comment: Very nice. +1, but exhausted my upvote already.

Comment: Just for fun: Perhaps some non-conforming "individuals" should look into the opposite direction? Like the eye or similar?

Comment: Minor difference, but visible. +1

Answer (score 18):

Approach:

- find a drawing
- digitize it, i.e. draw relevant coordinates and lines
- artistic touch: use thicker lines

Some directions for further improvements:

- modify arrow tips, e.g. triangular or curved
- use some kind of fill or texture, e.g. to mimick charcol strokes
- do some fine tuning, e.g. for the ears

[image: unicorn]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\tikz[line width=4.5pt]{
    % ~~~ head ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.96, 4.67)  to [out=88, in=95]   (3.22, 4.78);
    \draw (3.13, 4.63)  to [out=55, in=85]   (3.22, 4.43)
                        to [out=-45, in=105] (3.57, 3.79) 
                        to [out=288, in=85] (3.88, 2.86);
    \draw (3.77, 2.82)  to [out=230, in=280] (3.32, 2.73) 
                        to [out=90, in=300] (2.79, 3.34);
    \draw (2.84, 3.28)  to [out=185, in=270] (2.20, 3.92)  
                        to [out=250, in=160] (2.67, 2.83);
    % ~~~ eye ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.30, 4.10) to [out=190, in=160] (3.04, 4.04) 
                       to [out=300, in=190] (3.32, 3.93);
    % ~~~ nose ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.84, 2.83) -- (3.70, 3.00);
    % ~~~ hair ~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.89, 4.83)  to [out=180, in=90]  (1.78, 3.69) 
                        to [out=270, in=160] (2.90, 2.50);
    \draw (1.63, 4.24)  to [out=230, in=80] (2.14, .76);
    \draw (1.73,  .45)  to [out=70, in=270] (1.03, 3.04);
    \draw (1.61, 3.65)  to [out=260, in=140] (2.31, 2.29) 
                        to [out=-40, in=105] (3.34, 1.54);
    % ~~~ horn ~~~~~~
    \draw (3.48, 4.19)  to [out=35, in=30] (4.67, 5.22) 
                        to [out=35, in=30](3.65, 4.82);
    \draw (3.65, 4.34)  to [out=90 , in=280] (3.59, 4.69);
    \draw (3.85, 4.51)  to [out=90 , in=290] (3.79, 4.75);
    \draw (4.00, 4.64)  to [out=95 , in=290] (3.96, 4.83);
    \draw (4.19, 4.77)  to [out=95 , in=300] (4.16, 4.89);
}

\end{document}
```

**P.S.**: Again for the artistic touch, this is how it can appear when using dashed lines everywhere:

[image: dashed]

*(Might be a zebra-corn ...)*

**P.S.2**: More artistic, which makes it look more godzillian:

[image: decorated]

```
\tikz[line width=2pt,
    decoration={random steps,segment length=3pt}]{
    % ~~~ head ~~~~~~~~
    \draw [decorate] (2.96, 4.67)   to [out=88, in=95]   (3.22, 4.78);
...
```

Comment: Combining tools is also a technique GPT-4 is not (yet) 

Comment: Right, that's why I tend to say: "the intelligent component still sits at the outer side of the keyboard, i.e. in front of it ..."

Answer (score 17):

Two unicorns....

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{twemojis}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}
$\scaleto{\mbox{\twemoji{unicorn}}}{100pt}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{emoji}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\begin{document}

$\scaleto{\mbox{\emoji{unicorn}}}{100pt}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The second unicorn looks better.

Comment: @M.Logic It is typical for the children :-)

Answer (score 17):

Plot it.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[axis equal image]

    \addplot[no marks, domain={-0.95:1.85}] {-2*pow(x,5)+3.5*pow(x,4)};
    \addplot[no marks, domain={-0.95:3.5}] {-0.35*pow(x-0.5,2)+6.25};
    \addplot[no marks, domain={-3.5:-0.95}] {-0.15*x+5.25};
    \addplot[no marks, domain={-3.5:-0.95}] {-0.5*x+4};
    \addplot[no marks, domain={-180:180}] ({0.25*cos(x)-0.25}, {0.25*sin(x)+3.5});
    
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Approach:

- prepare a (simple) pixelated drawing
- place nodes like pixels, filled with some color

Details:

- most colors predefined
- `\pix` introduced as shorthand notation
- shown: classical lines with `\node ... {};`
- later: shorthands, with `;` being absorbed: `\pix{}{}{}`

Some ideas for refinement:

- node shapes yould be circle, triangle etc. to modify the pixels appearance
- pixels of same color could be placed by `for` loops
- a row or column of colored pixels could be coded for programming and decoded for drawing by tikz

[image: pixelated]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

% ~~~ (most) colors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\definecolor{pnk}{RGB}{244,173,203}
\definecolor{yel}{RGB}{245,233,49}
\definecolor{bld}{RGB}{110,181,233}
\definecolor{bll}{RGB}{180,220,246}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{145,200,239}

% ~~~ short hand notation ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\pix[3]{ \node [fill=#1] at (#2/4,#3/4) {};}

\begin{document}

\tikz{
    % ~~~ starting somewhere ~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [fill=pnk] at (0,0)   {};% so it begins
    \node [fill=bld] at (1/4,0) {};
    \node [fill=bll] at (2/4,0) {};
    \node [fill=blu] at (3/4,0) {};
    \node [fill=blu] at (4/4,0) {};
    \node [fill=pnk] at (5/4,0) {};
    \node [fill=bll] at (6/4,0) {};
    % ~~~ line(s) above ~~~~~~~~~
    \pix{pnk}{1}{1}% using short hand notation
    \pix{bld}{2}{1}
    \pix{pnk}{4}{1}
    \pix{bld}{5}{1}
    \pix{blu}{6}{1}
    \pix{blu}{7}{1}
    \pix{blu}{8}{1}

    \pix{pnk}{4}{2}
    \pix{bll}{5}{2}
    \pix{black}{6}{2}
    \pix{bll}{7}{2}
    \pix{bll}{8}{2}

    \pix{pnk}{4}{3}
    \pix{pnk}{5}{3}
    \pix{pnk}{6}{3}
    \pix{yel}{7}{3}

    \pix{pnk}{5}{4}
    \pix{pnk}{6}{4}
    \pix{yel}{8}{4}
    % ~~~ line(s) below ~~~~~~~~~~
    \pix{pnk}{1}{-1}
    \pix{blu}{2}{-1}
    \pix{blu}{3}{-1}
    \pix{blu}{4}{-1}
    \pix{bll}{5}{-1}
    \pix{blu}{6}{-1}

    \pix{pnk}{1}{-2}
    \pix{blu}{2}{-2}
    \pix{bll}{3}{-2}
    \pix{bld}{5}{-2}
    \pix{bll}{7}{-2}

    \pix{gray!40}{2}{-3}
    \pix{gray!40}{5}{-3}
    \pix{gray!40}{7}{-3}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Reminds me of [Q656670](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/656691/47927)

Answer (score 10):

Draw it using the totally experimental (but also already totally capable) `l3draw` package (okay, I have to admit that it is not Ti*k*Z then):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{l3draw}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\draw_begin:

\draw_linewidth:n { 2pt }

\color_select:n { black!50 }

\draw_path_moveto:n { 
    \draw_point_polar:nnn { 1.75cm } { 2cm } { 270 }
}
\draw_path_arc:nnnn { 270 } { 140 } { 1.75cm } { 2cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnnn { 240 } { 50 } { 0.25cm } { 0.25cm }
\draw_path_curveto:nn { -1.25cm , 2cm } { -1.75cm , 2cm }

\draw_path_moveto:n { 
    \draw_point_polar:nnn { 1.75cm } { 2cm } { 115 }
}
\draw_path_curveto:nn { -1.5cm , 2.5cm } { -2cm , 2.5cm }
\draw_path_curveto:nn { -2.5cm , 2cm } { -1.75cm , 1.5cm }

\draw_path_moveto:n { 
    \draw_point_polar:nnn { 1.75cm } { 2cm } { 270 }
}
\draw_path_arc:nnnn { 270 } { 400 } { 1.75cm } { 2cm }
\draw_path_arc:nnnn { 300 } { 480 } { 0.25cm } { 0.25cm }
\draw_path_curveto:nn { 1.25cm , 2cm } { 1.75cm , 2cm }

\draw_path_moveto:n { 
    \draw_point_polar:nnn { 1.75cm } { 2cm } { 65 }
}
\draw_path_curveto:nn { 1.5cm , 2.5cm } { 2cm , 2.5cm }
\draw_path_curveto:nn { 2.5cm , 2cm } { 1.75cm , 1.5cm }

\draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }

\color_select:n { black }

\draw_path_circle:nn { -0.75cm , 0.45cm } { 2.5mm } 
\draw_path_circle:nn { 0.75cm , 0.45cm } { 2.5mm } 

\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

\color_select:n { white }

\draw_path_circle:nn { -0.7cm , 0.5cm } { 0.9mm } 
\draw_path_circle:nn { 0.8cm , 0.5cm } { 0.9mm } 

\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

\color_select:n { black!50 }

\draw_path_ellipse:nnn { -0.5cm , -1.25cm } { 1mm , -0.5mm } { 0mm , 1.5mm } 
\draw_path_ellipse:nnn { 0.5cm , -1.25cm } { 1mm , 0.5mm } { 0mm , 1.5mm } 

\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill }

\color_stroke:n { yellow!75!red }
\color_fill:n { yellow!85!red }

\draw_path_moveto:n { -0.25cm , 2cm, }
\draw_path_lineto:n { 0cm , 3.75cm } 
\draw_path_lineto:n { 0.25cm , 2cm } 

\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill, stroke }

\color_stroke:n { magenta!85!cyan }
\color_fill:n { magenta }

\draw_path_moveto:n { 
    \draw_point_polar:nnn { 1.75cm } { 2cm } { 115 }
}
\draw_path_curveto:nnn { -0.75cm , 2.25cm } { -0.25cm , 2.25cm } { 1cm , 1.25cm }
\draw_path_curveto:nnn { -0.75cm , 3.25cm } { -1cm , 2.5cm } { 
    \draw_point_polar:nnn { 1.75cm } { 2cm } { 115 } 
}

\draw_path_use_clear:n { fill, stroke }

\draw_end:

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This actually lead to a [bug fix](https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/1195#issue-1667109323) since I initially wanted to use `\draw_path_arc_axes:nnnn` which ... did not work out well =)

Answer (score 9):

Let's criticise my previous [drawing with line strokes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681437/245790).

From research and knowledge:

- unicorns come with color
- rainbow-like colors are an important ingredient
- unicorns are fiction, held dearly by many

How to reflect these issues? One way to do it is using `tikz` features to process pathes. Let's apply `Artistic Intelligence` again.

[image: pathes]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes,shapes.geometric}% <<< NEW <<<


\begin{document}

\tikzset{% <<< NEW <<<
    paint/.style={draw=#1!50!black, fill=#1!50},
    my star/.style={decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=star},
    star points=#1}
}

\tikz[line width=1pt,decoration={shape sep=8pt,shape size=8pt}]{
    % ~~~ horn coloration ~~~~~~~~ <<< NEW <<<
    \draw [decoration={shape sep=11pt,shape size=10pt},my star=6, paint=yellow] 
          (4.67, 5.22) -- (3.25,4.4);
    % ~~~ head ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.96, 4.67)  to [out=88, in=95]   (3.22, 4.78);
    \draw (3.13, 4.63)  to [out=55, in=85]   (3.22, 4.43)
                        to [out=-45, in=105] (3.57, 3.79) 
                        to [out=288, in=85] (3.88, 2.86);
    \draw (3.77, 2.82)  to [out=230, in=280] (3.32, 2.73) 
                        to [out=90, in=300] (2.79, 3.34);
    \draw (2.84, 3.28)  to [out=185, in=270] (2.20, 3.92)
                        to [out=250, in=160] (2.67, 2.83);
    % ~~~ eye ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.30, 4.10) to [out=190, in=160] (3.04, 4.04) 
    to [out=300, in=190] (3.32, 3.93);
    % ~~~ nose ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.84, 2.83) -- (3.70, 3.00);
    % ~~~ hair ~~~~~~~ <<< MODIFIED <<<
    \draw [my star=5, paint=red] (2.89, 4.83) 
                        to [out=180, in=90]  (1.78, 3.69) 
                        to [out=270, in=160] (2.90, 2.50);
    \draw [my star=5, paint=orange] (1.63, 4.24)
                        to [out=230, in=80] (2.14, .76);
    \draw [my star=5, paint=blue] (1.73,  .45)  to [out=70, in=270] (1.03, 3.04);
    \draw [my star=5, paint=yellow] (1.61, 3.65)  
                        to [out=260, in=140] (2.31, 2.29) 
                        to [out=-40, in=105] (3.34, 1.54);
    % ~~~ horn ~~~~~~
    \draw (3.48, 4.19)  to [out=35, in=30] (4.67, 5.22) 
                        to [out=35, in=30](3.65, 4.82);
    \draw (3.65, 4.34)  to [out=90 , in=280] (3.59, 4.69);
    \draw (3.85, 4.51)  to [out=90 , in=290] (3.79, 4.75);
    \draw (4.00, 4.64)  to [out=95 , in=290] (3.96, 4.83);
    \draw (4.19, 4.77)  to [out=95 , in=300] (4.16, 4.89);
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can view the following code from two perspectives:

1. as a cheap trick
2. as an inventive solution.

---

Ad #1: That view should be obvious.

---

Ad #2: It provides the properties of an inventive solution:

- it IS TIKZ
- AND it IS NOT-TIKZ
- i.e. it's a resolution of a contradiction
- done by separation in code
- which can be perceived as the principle of "separating between part and whole" (overall it's tikz as a whole, but not-tikz in it's part(s))

Take that, AI ...

[image: result]

*Screenshot. Save as uniforn-f.png with or without the gray borders from my browsers background.*

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}%       tikz
\usepackage{graphicx}% NOT-tikz

\begin{document}

\tikz{\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics{unicorn-f.png}};}% AND (tikz AND not-tikz)

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hehe, kudos for finding the gap in the question (+1, but I also add a comment to the question to prevent more of those xD)

Answer (score 6):

Let's apply some `Artistic Intelligence` on my [line-stroke-drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my8iX.png). To give it a `cubistic touch` let's introduce some colored areas by:

1. just filling some strokes
2. introducing new colored shapes

Though it builds on the previous approach the concept is slightly different, using other properties `tikz` provide in two different ways.

Are the results pleasing? When to stop, where to continue? Humans decide, humans know,  ...

---

**Ad #1**: Results for 1.5 pt and 4.5 pt line thickness AND filling the hair-strokes.

[image: 1pt5]
[image: 4pt5]

```
...
    % ~~~ hair ~~~~~~~
    \draw [fill=gray] (1.63, 4.24)  to [out=230, in=80] (2.14, .76);
    \draw [fill=gray] (1.73,  .45)  to [out=70, in=270] (1.03, 3.04);
    \draw [fill=gray] (1.61, 3.65)  to [out=260, in=140] (2.31, 2.29) 
                        to [out=-40, in=105] (3.34, 1.54);
    \draw [fill=gray] (2.89, 4.83)  to [out=180, in=90]  (1.78, 3.69) 
                        to [out=270, in=160] (2.90, 2.50);
...
```

---

**Ad #2**: Just adding a few colored shapes before drawing the strokes.

[image: colored shapes]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\tikz[line width=4.5pt]{
    % ~~~ colored shapes ~~~~
    \draw [fill=yellow!60,draw=none] 
        (3.2,4.7) -- (4.3,5.5) -- (4.9,5.35) -- (3.3,4.3) -- cycle; 
    \draw [fill=blue!50,draw=none] 
        (.5,3) -- (1,3.5) -- (2,1) -- (1.5,.5) -- cycle;    
    \draw [fill=pink!60,draw=none] 
        (1.2,3.8) -- (1.6,4.5) -- (1.6,1.3) -- (2.,2) -- cycle; 
    \draw [fill=orange!50,draw=none] 
        (1.5,3.8) -- (2.8,.9) -- (3.8,1.6) --  cycle;   
    
    
    % ~~~ head ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.96, 4.67)  to [out=88, in=95]   (3.22, 4.78);
    \draw (3.13, 4.63)  to [out=55, in=85]   (3.22, 4.43)
                        to [out=-45, in=105] (3.57, 3.79) 
                        to [out=288, in=85] (3.88, 2.86);
    \draw (3.77, 2.82)  to [out=230, in=280] (3.32, 2.73) 
                        to [out=90, in=300] (2.79, 3.34);
    \draw (2.84, 3.28)  to [out=185, in=270] (2.20, 3.92)  
                        to [out=250, in=160] (2.67, 2.83);
    % ~~~ eye ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.30, 4.10) to [out=190, in=160] (3.04, 4.04) 
    to [out=300, in=190] (3.32, 3.93);
    % ~~~ nose ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.84, 2.83) -- (3.70, 3.00);
    % ~~~ hair ~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.89, 4.83)  to [out=180, in=90]  (1.78, 3.69) 
                        to [out=270, in=160] (2.90, 2.50);
    \draw (1.63, 4.24)  to [out=230, in=80] (2.14, .76);
    \draw (1.73,  .45)  to [out=70, in=270] (1.03, 3.04);
    \draw (1.61, 3.65)  to [out=260, in=140] (2.31, 2.29) 
                        to [out=-40, in=105] (3.34, 1.54);
    % ~~~ horn ~~~~~~
    \draw (3.48, 4.19)  to [out=35, in=30] (4.67, 5.22) 
                        to [out=35, in=30](3.65, 4.82);
    \draw (3.65, 4.34)  to [out=90 , in=280] (3.59, 4.69);
    \draw (3.85, 4.51)  to [out=90 , in=290] (3.79, 4.75);
    \draw (4.00, 4.64)  to [out=95 , in=290] (3.96, 4.83);
    \draw (4.19, 4.77)  to [out=95 , in=300] (4.16, 4.89);
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

"Diamonds are forever ...", said "The last unicorn" ;-)

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    unic/.pic={
    % ~~~ colored shapes ~~~~
    \draw [fill=yellow!60,draw=none] (3.2,4.7) -- (4.3,5.5) -- (4.9,5.35) -- (3.3,4.3) -- cycle;    
    \draw [fill=red!20,draw=none] (0,4.2) -- (.3,.9) -- (4.2,1.6) -- (4.5,3.5) --  cycle;       
    
    % ~~~ head ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.96, 4.67)  to [out=88, in=95]   (3.22, 4.78);
    \draw (3.13, 4.63)  to [out=55, in=85]   (3.22, 4.43) to [out=-45, in=105] (3.57, 3.79) to [out=288, in=85] (3.88, 2.86);
    \draw (3.77, 2.82)  to [out=230, in=280] (3.32, 2.73) to [out=90, in=300] (2.79, 3.34);
    \draw (2.84, 3.28)  to [out=185, in=270] (2.20, 3.92) to [out=250, in=160] (2.67, 2.83);
    % ~~~ eye ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.30, 4.10) to [out=190, in=160] (3.04, 4.04) to [out=300, in=190] (3.32, 3.93);
    % ~~~ nose ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.84, 2.83) -- (3.70, 3.00);
    % ~~~ hair ~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.89, 4.83)  to [out=180, in=90]  (1.78, 3.69) to [out=270, in=160] (2.90, 2.50);
    \draw (1.63, 4.24)  to [out=230, in=80] (2.14, .76);
    \draw (1.73,  .45)  to [out=70, in=270] (1.03, 3.04);
    \draw (1.61, 3.65)  to [out=260, in=140] (2.31, 2.29) to [out=-40, in=105] (3.34, 1.54);
    % ~~~ horn ~~~~~~
    \draw (3.48, 4.19)  to [out=35, in=30] (4.67, 5.22) to [out=35, in=30](3.65, 4.82);
    \draw (3.65, 4.34)  to [out=90 , in=280] (3.59, 4.69);
    \draw (3.85, 4.51)  to [out=90 , in=290] (3.79, 4.75);
    \draw (4.00, 4.64)  to [out=95 , in=290] (3.96, 4.83);
    \draw (4.19, 4.77)  to [out=95 , in=300] (4.16, 4.89);
}}

\tikzset{% diamond
    dmnd/.pic={\draw [fill=red,line width=2.5pt] (-.7,0) -- (0,1.1) -- (.7,0) -- (0,-1.1)-- cycle;}
}

\tikzset{% half card
    half/.pic={
    \pic at (0,0) [line width=2.5pt] {unic};
    \pic at (-1,5.5) [scale=.7, transform shape] {dmnd};
}}

\tikz{% á la card ...
    \pic at (-2.5,-.5) {half};
    \pic at (+2.5,+.5) [rotate=180,transform shape] {half};
    \draw (-4.5,-7) [rounded corners=10pt,line width=4pt] rectangle ++(9,14);
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Let's show 2 unicorns, inspired by what we know from gables or blazons, like here:

[image: basic idea]

The code below basically does two things:

- combine two [previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681500/245790) drawings I [posted](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681437/245790) here as `tikz pics`
- shift the two `\pic`s against each other via the "constant" `\newcommand\shft[0]{1}`

Relevant code section:

```
\tikz{
    \pic             at (-\shft,0) {beauty};
    \pic [xscale=-1] at (+\shft,0) {uni};
}
```

For `shft=1`, this is the result:

[image: shift=1]

But it's also fun to see what happens for 0, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4 and 5. Wrt. `AI` they can be generated easily, but not all will be appreciated as nice, esthtic or beautiful. Some may appear disturbing, or like taken from a test from psychology. The last one even qualifies for "telling a story by one picture". Or in techno-speak: `shft` introduces a lot of `noise` for us humans.

[image: shift=0]
[image: shift=2]
[image: shift=2.5]
[image: shift=3]
[image: shift=3.5]
[image: shift=4]
[image: shift=5]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes,shapes.geometric}

\newcommand\shft[0]{1}% shift amount for the \pic's

\begin{document}

\tikzset{% needed for beauty-corn
    paint/.style={draw=#1!50!black, fill=#1!50},
    my star/.style={decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=star},
    star points=#1}
}

\tikzset{% beaty-corn, as one-liners
    beauty/.style={line width=1pt,decoration={shape sep=8pt,shape size=8pt}},
    beauty/.pic={
    % ~~~ horn coloration ~~~~~~~~ 
    \draw [decoration={shape sep=11pt,shape size=10pt},my star=6, paint=yellow] 
          (4.67, 5.22) -- (3.25,4.4);
    % ~~~ head ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.96, 4.67)  to [out=88, in=95]   (3.22, 4.78);\draw (3.13, 4.63)    to [out=55, in=85]   (3.22, 4.43) to [out=-45, in=105] (3.57, 3.79) to [out=288, in=85] (3.88, 2.86);\draw (3.77, 2.82)  to [out=230, in=280] (3.32, 2.73) to [out=90, in=300] (2.79, 3.34);\draw (2.84, 3.28)  to [out=185, in=270] (2.20, 3.92) to [out=250, in=160] (2.67, 2.83);
    % ~~~ eye ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.30, 4.10) to [out=190, in=160] (3.04, 4.04) to [out=300, in=190] (3.32, 3.93);
    % ~~~ nose ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.84, 2.83) -- (3.70, 3.00);
    % ~~~ hair ~~~~~~~ 
    \draw [my star=5, paint=red] (2.89, 4.83) to [out=180, in=90]  (1.78, 3.69) to [out=270, in=160] (2.90, 2.50);\draw [my star=5, paint=orange] (1.63, 4.24) to [out=230, in=80] (2.14, .76);\draw [my star=5, paint=blue] (1.73,  .45)  to [out=70, in=270] (1.03, 3.04);\draw [my star=5, paint=yellow] (1.61, 3.65) to [out=260, in=140] (2.31, 2.29) to [out=-40, in=105] (3.34, 1.54);
    % ~~~ horn ~~~~~~
    \draw (3.48, 4.19)  to [out=35, in=30] (4.67, 5.22) to [out=35, in=30](3.65, 4.82);\draw (3.65, 4.34)   to [out=90 , in=280] (3.59, 4.69);\draw (3.85, 4.51)    to [out=90 , in=290] (3.79, 4.75);\draw (4.00, 4.64)    to [out=95 , in=290] (3.96, 4.83);\draw (4.19, 4.77)    to [out=95 , in=300] (4.16, 4.89);
}}

\tikzset{% uni-corn, as one-liners
    uni/.style={line width=4.5pt,decorate,decoration={mirror=true}},
    uni/.pic={
    % ~~~ head ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.96, 4.67)  to [out=88, in=95]   (3.22, 4.78);\draw (3.13, 4.63)    to [out=55, in=85]   (3.22, 4.43) to [out=-45, in=105] (3.57, 3.79) to [out=288, in=85] (3.88, 2.86);\draw (3.77, 2.82)  to [out=230, in=280] (3.32, 2.73) to [out=90, in=300] (2.79, 3.34);\draw (2.84, 3.28)  to [out=185, in=270] (2.20, 3.92) to [out=250, in=160] (2.67, 2.83);
    % ~~~ eye ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.30, 4.10) to [out=190, in=160] (3.04, 4.04) to [out=300, in=190] (3.32, 3.93);
    % ~~~ nose ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.84, 2.83) -- (3.70, 3.00);
    % ~~~ hair ~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.89, 4.83)  to [out=180, in=90]  (1.78, 3.69) to [out=270, in=160] (2.90, 2.50);\draw (1.63, 4.24)  to [out=230, in=80] (2.14, .76);\draw (1.73,  .45)  to [out=70, in=270] (1.03, 3.04);\draw (1.61, 3.65)  to [out=260, in=140] (2.31, 2.29) to [out=-40, in=105] (3.34, 1.54);
    % ~~~ horn ~~~~~~
    \draw (3.48, 4.19)  to [out=35, in=30] (4.67, 5.22)  to [out=35, in=30](3.65, 4.82);\draw (3.65, 4.34)  to [out=90 , in=280] (3.59, 4.69);\draw (3.85, 4.51)    to [out=90 , in=290] (3.79, 4.75);\draw (4.00, 4.64)    to [out=95 , in=290] (3.96, 4.83);\draw (4.19, 4.77)    to [out=95 , in=300] (4.16, 4.89);
}}

\tikz{
    \pic             at (-\shft,0) {beauty};
    \pic [xscale=-1] at (+\shft,0) {uni};
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: did you really post 7 separate answers lol

Comment: Looks like … and I‘m not done yet, following different concepts one by one :)

Answer (score 5):

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,decorations.shapes,shapes.geometric}

% ~~~ (most) colors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\definecolor{pnk}{RGB}{244,173,203}
\definecolor{yel}{RGB}{245,233,49}
\definecolor{bld}{RGB}{110,181,233}
\definecolor{bll}{RGB}{180,220,246}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{145,200,239}

% ~~~ short hand notation ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\pix[3]{ \node [fill=#1] at (#2/4,#3/4) {};}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{% needed for beauty-corn
    paint/.style={draw=#1!50!black, fill=#1!50},
    my star/.style={decorate,decoration={shape backgrounds,shape=star},
    star points=#1}
}

\tikzset{% beaty-corn, as one-liners
    beauty/.style={line width=1pt,decoration={shape sep=8pt,shape size=8pt}},
    beauty/.pic={
    % ~~~ horn coloration ~~~~~~~~ 
    \draw [decoration={shape sep=11pt,shape size=10pt},my star=6, paint=yellow] 
          (4.67, 5.22) -- (3.25,4.4);
    % ~~~ head ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (2.96, 4.67)  to [out=88, in=95]   (3.22, 4.78);\draw (3.13, 4.63)    to [out=55, in=85]   (3.22, 4.43) to [out=-45, in=105] (3.57, 3.79) to [out=288, in=85] (3.88, 2.86);\draw (3.77, 2.82)  to [out=230, in=280] (3.32, 2.73) to [out=90, in=300] (2.79, 3.34);\draw (2.84, 3.28)  to [out=185, in=270] (2.20, 3.92) to [out=250, in=160] (2.67, 2.83);
    % ~~~ eye ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.30, 4.10) to [out=190, in=160] (3.04, 4.04) to [out=300, in=190] (3.32, 3.93);
    % ~~~ nose ~~~~~~~~
    \draw (3.84, 2.83) -- (3.70, 3.00);
    % ~~~ hair ~~~~~~~ 
    \draw [my star=5, paint=red] (2.89, 4.83) to [out=180, in=90]  (1.78, 3.69) to [out=270, in=160] (2.90, 2.50);\draw [my star=5, paint=orange] (1.63, 4.24) to [out=230, in=80] (2.14, .76);\draw [my star=5, paint=blue] (1.73,  .45)  to [out=70, in=270] (1.03, 3.04);\draw [my star=5, paint=yellow] (1.61, 3.65) to [out=260, in=140] (2.31, 2.29) to [out=-40, in=105] (3.34, 1.54);
    % ~~~ horn ~~~~~~
    \draw (3.48, 4.19)  to [out=35, in=30] (4.67, 5.22) to [out=35, in=30](3.65, 4.82);\draw (3.65, 4.34)   to [out=90 , in=280] (3.59, 4.69);\draw (3.85, 4.51)    to [out=90 , in=290] (3.79, 4.75);\draw (4.00, 4.64)    to [out=95 , in=290] (3.96, 4.83);\draw (4.19, 4.77)    to [out=95 , in=300] (4.16, 4.89);
}}

\tikzset{
    bitcorn/.pic={
    % ~~~ starting somewhere ~~~~~~~~~~
    \node [fill=pnk] at (0,0)   {};% so it begins
    \node [fill=bld] at (1/4,0) {};\node [fill=bll] at (2/4,0) {};
    \node [fill=blu] at (3/4,0) {};\node [fill=blu] at (4/4,0) {};
    \node [fill=pnk] at (5/4,0) {};\node [fill=bll] at (6/4,0) {};
    % ~~~ line(s) above ~~~~~~~~~
    \pix{pnk}{1}{1}% using short hand notation
    \pix{bld}{2}{1}\pix{pnk}{4}{1}\pix{bld}{5}{1}\pix{blu}{6}{1}\pix{blu}{7}{1}\pix{blu}{8}{1}
    \pix{pnk}{4}{2}\pix{bll}{5}{2}\pix{black}{6}{2}\pix{bll}{7}{2}\pix{bll}{8}{2}
    \pix{pnk}{4}{3}\pix{pnk}{5}{3}\pix{pnk}{6}{3}\pix{yel}{7}{3}
    \pix{pnk}{5}{4}\pix{pnk}{6}{4}\pix{yel}{8}{4}
    % ~~~ line(s) below ~~~~~~~~~~
    \pix{pnk}{1}{-1}\pix{blu}{2}{-1}\pix{blu}{3}{-1}\pix{blu}{4}{-1}\pix{bll}{5}{-1}\pix{blu}{6}{-1}
    \pix{pnk}{1}{-2}\pix{blu}{2}{-2}\pix{bll}{3}{-2}\pix{bld}{5}{-2}\pix{bll}{7}{-2}
    \pix{gray!40}{2}{-3}\pix{gray!40}{5}{-3}\pix{gray!40}{7}{-3}
}}

\tikz{
    % text
    \node [draw,inner ysep=2em,inner xsep=3em,rounded corners=20pt,line width=3pt] at (-8,4) {\Huge{Once upon a time \dots}};
    
    % dream
    \node at (1,0) [draw,cloud callout,cloud puffs=15,callout relative pointer={(215:3cm)}, callout pointer segments=3,ball color=orange,inner color=yellow!70,outer color=orange!70] {\tikz{\pic [xscale=-1] {beauty};}};
    
    % dreamer
    \pic at (-12,-8) [scale=2.5,transform shape] {bitcorn};
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For your entertainment I tried [phind.com](https://www.phind.com)  on the unicorns. In contrast to ChatGPT it claims to access the internet and uses links, i.e. actual information, with focus on programming.

Being closer to a search engine it also displays related links ... though it's not always clear, how it obtained the solution from said links. This seems to be a feature of GPT (General Pre-Trained language models, which can't be or map knowledge models). *(GPT-3.5, long answer)*

Enjoy the results.

#### draw a unicorn with tikz, to be used in latex.

Could be worse ...

[image: result 1]

#### draw a detailed unicorn with tikz, to be used in latex. show the complete code, please.

qed ...

[image: result 2]

#### Code

As produced, without indenting, just combined into one.

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}% my edit
%\documentclass{article}% as proposed
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Body
\filldraw[color=white, fill=white] (0,0) circle (2);
% Horn
\filldraw[color=yellow, fill=yellow] (0,2) -- (-0.5,4) -- (0.5,4) -- cycle;
% Mane
\filldraw[color=pink, fill=pink] (-1,1) -- (-2,3) -- (-1,3) -- cycle;
\filldraw[color=pink, fill=pink] (1,1) -- (2,3) -- (1,3) -- cycle;
% Tail
\draw[color=blue, ultra thick] (0,-2) -- (0,-4);
% Eyes
\filldraw[color=black, fill=black] (-0.5,0.5) circle (0.1);
\filldraw[color=black, fill=black] (0.5,0.5) circle (0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Body
\filldraw[gray!50] (0,0) circle (2cm);
% Legs
\draw[gray, thick] (-1.5,-1) -- (-1.5,-3);
\draw[gray, thick] (1.5,-1) -- (1.5,-3);
% Horn
\draw[gray, thick] (0,2) -- (0,4);
% Eyes
\filldraw[black] (-0.5,0.5) circle (0.1cm);
\filldraw[black] (0.5,0.5) circle (0.1cm);
% Label
\node[anchor=north] at (0,-3.5) {Unicorn};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

#### P.S.: some "refinement"

Following some guide how to formulate prompts (input to such interfaces), I tried the following. Please judge for yourself ...

Prompt/instruction: *Draw a unicorn using tikz, so I can use it with Latex. Make it detailed. Avoid using simple shapes, i.e. avoid triangles, avoid circles, avoid simple lines, use more sophisticated elements. Output the complete code so I can copy it.*

[image: result 3]

```
% Draw a unicorn using tikz, so I can use it with Latex. Make it detailed. Avoid using simple shapes, i.e. avoid triangles, avoid circles, avoid simple lines, use more sophisticated elements. Output the complete code so I can copy it.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
% Head
\fill[white] (0,0) circle (4);
% Eyes
\fill[black] (-1,1.5) circle (0.5);
\fill[black] (1,1.5) circle (0.5);
% Horn
\draw[gray, line width=2] (0,0) -- (0,4);
% Ears
\fill[gray] (-3,3) -- (-2,4) -- (-1,3) -- cycle;
\fill[gray] (3,3) -- (2,4) -- (1,3) -- cycle;
% Mane
\fill[blue!50] (-4,0) to[out=90,in=180] (-3,2) to[out=0,in=180] (-2,4) to[out=0,in=180] (2,4) to[out=0,in=180] (3,2) to[out=0,in=90] (4,0);
% Body
\fill[pink] (-4,0) to[out=270,in=180] (-2,-2) to[out=0,in=180] (2,-2) to[out=0,in=270] (4,0);
% Legs
\fill[gray] (-3,-4) rectangle (-1,-2);
\fill[gray] (3,-4) rectangle (1,-2);
% Hooves
\fill[black] (-2.5,-4) rectangle (-1.5,-3.5);
\fill[black] (2.5,-4) rectangle (1.5,-3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To make the "head" visible, I changed it to:

```
% Head
\fill[yellow!50] (0,0) circle (4);
```

[image: result 4]

One of us probably needs to study unicorn anatomy ...

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look at a new `tikz bread`, which:

- builds on the [pixeled unicorn by tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681460/245790)
- and introduces a new bread
- which still follows this [inventive solution concept](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681431/245790)
- just like [this extension did](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681468/245790)

The parameter set for the scale determines the esthetics of the result.

[image: uni-masto-corn]
*Scale as given in code*

[image: scale = 0.0125]
*Scale set to 0.0125*

[image: 0.0225]
*Scale set to 0.0225*

```
\documentclass[10pt, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}

% ~~~ (most) colors ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\definecolor{pnk}{RGB}{244,173,203}
\definecolor{yel}{RGB}{245,233,49}
\definecolor{bld}{RGB}{110,181,233}
\definecolor{bll}{RGB}{180,220,246}
\definecolor{blu}{RGB}{145,200,239}

% ~~~ NEW: short hand notation with animal magic ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\newcommand\pix[3]{ \pic [fill=#1,scale=0.0185,transform shape] at (#2/4,#3/4) {masto};}

\begin{document}

% ~~~ a pic-ture here and a pic-ture there, 
%     tikz picture is that place where ...
\tikzset{% guess the bread <<< NEW
    masto/.pic={
    % ~~~ ele ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [fill=#1,line width=.4pt, draw=black!80]% 
        (6,0) .. controls +(0:3.4) and +(-90:-3.4) ..%
        (12,-4) -- (12,-6.6)        .. controls +(90:-3) and +(0:3)  ..%
        (6,-9.97)   .. controls +(0:-1) and +(-10:1) ..%    
        (3.4,-9.64) .. controls +(-80:1) and +(0:-2) ..%
        (6,-12)     .. controls +(0:1) and +(30:-1) ..%
        (8.2,-11.3) -- (8.3,-12.4)  .. controls +(30:-1) and +(0:1) ..%
        (5.55,-13)  .. controls +(0:-4) and +(90:-5) ..%        
        (0,-6.6) -- (0,-4)  .. controls +(90:3.4) and +(0:-3.4) ..%     
        (6,0);%     
    % ~~~ m ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw [fill=green!20, line join=round, cap=round, 
        line width=.4pt, draw=black!80]%
        (2.1,-7.9) --  (2.1,-4.4)   .. controls +(90:1.5) and +(0:-1) ..%
        (4.15,-2.15).. controls +(0:1) and +(-60:-1) ..%
        (6,-3.5)    .. controls +(60:1) and +(0:-1) ..%     
        (7.9,-2.15) .. controls +(0:1) and +(90:1.5) ..%        
        (9.9,-4.4) -- (9.9,-7.9) -- (8.5,-7.9) --% 
        (8.5,-4.4)  .. controls +(90:.5) and +(180:-.5) ..% 
        (7.6,-3.5)  .. controls +(0:-.5) and +(90:.5) ..%
        (6.7,-4.4) -- (6.7,-6.6) -- (5.3,-6.6) -- (5.3,-4.4)% 
                    .. controls +(90:.5) and +(180:-.5) ..% 
        (4.4,-3.5)  .. controls +(0:-.5) and +(-90:-.5) ..%
        (3.53,-4.4) -- (3.53,-7.9) -- (2.1,-7.9);%
}}

% ~~~ unicorns can come in pixels ...
\tikz{% <<< rearranged
    % ~~~ starting somewhere ~~~~~~~~~~
    \pix{pnk}{0}{0}\pix{bld}{1}{0}\pix{bll}{2}{0}\pix{blu}{3}{0}\pix{blu}{4}{0}\pix{pnk}{5}{0}\pix{bll}{6}{0}   
    % ~~~ line(s) above ~~~~~~~~~
    \pix{pnk}{1}{1}\pix{bld}{2}{1}\pix{pnk}{4}{1}\pix{bld}{5}{1}\pix{blu}{6}{1}\pix{blu}{7}{1}\pix{blu}{8}{1}
    \pix{pnk}{4}{2}\pix{bll}{5}{2}\pix{black}{6}{2}\pix{bll}{7}{2}\pix{bll}{8}{2}
    \pix{pnk}{4}{3}\pix{pnk}{5}{3}\pix{pnk}{6}{3}\pix{yel}{7}{3}
    \pix{pnk}{5}{4}\pix{pnk}{6}{4}\pix{yel}{8}{4}
    % ~~~ line(s) below ~~~~~~~~~~
    \pix{pnk}{1}{-1}\pix{blu}{2}{-1}\pix{blu}{3}{-1}\pix{blu}{4}{-1}\pix{bll}{5}{-1}\pix{blu}{6}{-1}
    \pix{pnk}{1}{-2}\pix{blu}{2}{-2}\pix{bll}{3}{-2}\pix{bld}{5}{-2}\pix{bll}{7}{-2}
    \pix{gray!40}{2}{-3}\pix{gray!40}{5}{-3}\pix{gray!40}{7}{-3}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: These are not unicorns.

Comment: Check the link’s carefully.

Comment: I don't need to click on your external (possibly malicious) links to know that these are not unicorns.

Comment: ?? None are external which you can easily verify by hovering over them ... // So, I've got your statement. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hovering with my finger does nothing on an Android touch-screen device.