# How to make an \egreg command?

Tags: loops, fun

I would like a command `\egreg` which produces “egreg”. However, there is no reason to limit yourself to one “reg”. Who knows, maybe one day you just feel like writing “egregregregreg" for some reason.  So the command should also take an optional argument, specifying the number of “reg”’s you want.

I know there are easy solutions involving loops, but given that it’s April 1, the most ridiculous solution will be accepted.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand\egreg{o}{%
    % something
}

\begin{document}

\egreg % should produce "egreg"
\egreg[0] % should produce "eg"
\egreg[1] % should produce "egreg"
\egreg[2] % should produce "egregreg"
\egreg[5] % should produce "egregregregregreg"

Perhaps we might also want to allow negative values:

\egreg[-1] % should produce "regeg"
\egreg[-2] % should produce "regregeg"

Maybe also complex values?

\egreg[i] % perhaps "$\text{eg} + i\text{reg}$"?

Perhaps someone can also figure out
what to do with quaternionic values?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great April 1st post! I'm sure egreg will answer :D

Comment: I first thought that this was about a macro that outputs marvellous solutions to (or even just magically solve on-the-fly) tricky TeX problems whenever being used in your code ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht I promise that if you can come up with a command that can do that consistently, your answer will also be accepted and appropriately awarded. But `\newcommand\egreg[1]{Ask ChatGPT about #1}` doesn’t count. 

Comment: I think, on April 1st, the macro should output variations of the string `april` instead of `egreg` ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht “aprilprilprilprilprilprilprilprilprilpril 1”?

Comment: How very egregious.

Comment: For a moment I parsed that command as `\egrep` and started wondering what the application of the **egrep** *NIX command in a LaTeX document could be. I opted for an April's fools joke, but the wrong joke! So you fooled me twice! :-)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think the image-inary part should be drawn with TikZlings:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikzlings}
\newcommand{\egregnum}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
    every node/.style={inner sep=0pt}, 
    baseline=(a0.base)
    ]
    \node (a0) {eg};
    \ifnumgreater{#1}{0}{%
    \foreach \x [count=\prev from 0] in {1,...,#1}
        \node[anchor=west] (a\x) at (a\prev.east){reg};
        }{%
    \ifnumless{#1}{0}{%
        \foreach \x [evaluate=\x as \numpos using int(\x * -1),
                    evaluate=\x as \prev using int((\x * -1)-1)] 
                    in {-1,...,#1}                  
                \node[anchor=east] (a\numpos) at (a\prev.west){reg};            
            }{}%
        }%
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }

\newcommand{\egregimm}{%
           \raisebox{-.3cm}{\begin{tikzpicture}
                \tikzling[
        scale=0.5,signpost={reg}
        ]
            \end{tikzpicture}
            }}
    
\newcommand{\egreg}[1][1]{%
    \IfDecimal{#1}{%
        \egregnum{#1}%
        }{%
        \StrDel{#1}{ }[\complesso]%
        \StrSubstitute{\complesso}{-}{+}[\contasegni]%
        \StrCount{\contasegni}{+}[\numsegni]%
        \StrPosition[\numsegni]{\contasegni}{+}[\signposition]%
        \StrChar{\complesso}{\signposition}[\segno]%
        \IfStrEq{\segno}{-}{%immaginario negativo
            \StrBehind[\numsegni]{#1}{-}[\partei]%
            \StrSubstitute{\partei}{ }{}[\parteimm]%
            \StrSubstitute{\parteimm}{i}{}[\immaginario]%
            \IfDecimal{\immaginario}{%
                \foreach \cifreimm in {1,...,\immaginario}{\egregimm}
                }{%
                \egregimm
                }%
            \StrBefore[\numsegni]{\complesso}{-}[\reale]%
            \IfDecimal{\reale}{%
                \egregnum{\reale}
                }{%
                \egregnum{0}
                }%
        }{% immaginario positivo
            \StrBefore{\complesso}{+}[\reale]%
            \IfDecimal{\reale}{%
                \egregnum{\reale}
                }{%
                \egregnum{0}
                }%
            \StrBehind{#1}{+}[\partei]%
            \StrSubstitute{\partei}{ }{}[\parteimm]%
            \StrSubstitute{\parteimm}{i}{}[\immaginario]%
            \IfDecimal{\immaginario}{%
                \foreach \cifreimm in {1,...,\immaginario}{\egregimm}
                }{%
                \egregimm
                }%
        }%
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \verb|\egreg|: \egreg % should produce "egreg"
    
    \verb|\egreg[0]|: \egreg[0] % should produce "eg"
    
    \verb|\egreg[1]|: \egreg[1] % should produce "egreg"
    
    \verb|\egreg[2]|: \egreg[2] % should produce "egregreg"
    
    \verb|\egreg[5]|: \egreg[5] % should produce "egregregregregreg"
    
    \verb|\egreg[-1]|: \egreg[-1] % should produce "regeg"
    
    \verb|\egreg[-2]|: \egreg[-2] % should produce "regregeg"
    
    \verb|\egreg[i]|: \egreg[i] % perhaps "$\text{eg} + i\text{reg}$"?

        \verb|\egreg[3+2i]|: \egreg[3+2i] 

        \verb|\egreg[2 + 3i]|: \egreg[2 + 3i]

        \verb|\egreg[-2 + 4i]|: \egreg[-2 + 4i]

        \verb|\egreg[1 - 2i]|: \egreg[1 - 2i]

        \verb|\egreg[-2 - i]|: \egreg[-2 - i]
 
        \verb|\egreg[-i]|: \egreg[-i]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can I hug it? 

Comment: @Gaussler Of course, you can! And they will be very happy of it!

Comment: The TikZlings won the competition for you. Congratulations!

Comment: @Gaussler I'm very proud if it! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, minor detail, but it seems that `\egreg[i]` behaves like `\egreg[1+i]` rather than `\egreg[0+i]`. Can’t say I care that much, given that this is all a joke anyway, but thought I’d let you know. 

Comment: More confirmation of the TeX.se adage "If you want more rep, add a picture". :)

Comment: @AlanMunn The question says "the most ridiculous solution will be accepted."

Comment: @Gaussler I corrected it!

Comment: I think the metapost version is more subtle.

Comment: @user206750 egreg rewarded it, indeed

Answer (score 20):

Out of competition, of course. The most ridiculous answers will be rewarded with bounty points.

Since you don't want expandability, as witnessed by the proposed syntax, here's my version. Note how most endlines are not masked with `%` and the abundance of unneeded spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand{\egreg}{o}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\printegreg{1}}{\printegreg{#1}}%
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printegreg}{m}{%
  $
  \begingroup\uccode`~ = `m \uppercase{\endgroup\def~}{\hbox{reg}}
  \mathcode`m = "8000
  \ifnum#1<0 \romannumeral-\number\number#1 000 \fi
  \hbox{eg}
  \ifnum#1>0 \romannumeral\number\number#1 000 \fi
  $%
}

\newcounter{egreg}
\newcount\plainegreg

\begin{document}

\egreg \  should produce ``egreg''

\egreg[0] should produce ``eg''

\egreg[1] should produce ``egreg''

\egreg[2] should produce ``egregreg''

\egreg[5] should produce ``egregregregregreg''

\egreg[-1] should produce ``regeg''

\egreg[-2] should produce ``regregeg''

\setcounter{egreg}{4}

\egreg[\value{egreg}]

\plainegreg=-3

\egreg[\plainegreg]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. But happened to complex-valued egreg? :-)

Comment: @Mico I'm real, not imaginary.

Comment: Well, we all have our complexities, don’t we?

Comment: If I offended you with this competition, I deeply “regreg” it. 

Comment: @Gaussler Not in the least! I'll award bounties to the most ridiculous answers.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to make the “regreg” pun. 

Comment: @Gaussler That's an egregious pun! :-)

Comment: @gusbrs egregregegious, even

Comment: @N.Virgo eg(reg)ⁿious for n → ∞.

Comment: I already chose my winner. The TikZlings were the determining factor. However, now it should be possible to add bounties and award answers, if you still feel like doing that. 

Comment: @Gaussler I started a bounty, maybe it will attract more ridiculousness. :-)

Comment: Come on, can’t you even spare a 1.1 million bounty? 

Comment: @egreg "I'm real, not imaginary" I was hoping to multiply two egreg together and obtain -egreg, dang!

Answer (score 18):

I think the best way to thank egreg for all the help was to solve this exercise using a code roughly as readable as most LaTeX code I can read on this forum (in particular yours egreg, but it's not your fault if LaTeX is not really readable :-P)… but a bit prettified (I took the liberty to modify the minus version to actually be a true inverse, i.e. equal when reading backward).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{bxbluf} % See below, from https://gist.github.com/zr-tex8r/7527995

\procbf{\egregBF}{
         +>,-----           --------         
       ------------       ------------       
      --------[<[-]>     ++++++++++++++      
     ++++++++++++++++   +++++++++++++++[     
    >[>++++++++++<-]>   [-<+>]<<---------    
    ------------------ ------------------    
   ---[>+<-],]++++++++ +++++++++++++++++++   
   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++   
   +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.++.   
  [-]>[->++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  
  +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++.-  
    ------------.++.[-]<],[--------------    
     -------------------------------]]<[     
      [-]>,[>[>++++++++++<-]>[-<+>]<<--      
       -------------------------------       
        ---------------[>+<-],]>[->++        
        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++        
         +++++++++++++++++++++++++++         
          +++++++++++++++++++++++++          
           ++++++++++++++++++++.--           
            .+++++++++++++.[-]<]+            
             +++++++++++++++++++             
              +++++++++++++++++              
               +++++++++++++++               
               +++++++++++++++               
                +++++++++++++                
                 +++++++++++                 
                  +++++++++                  
                   +++.--.                   
                    [-]]♥                    
                     ♥♥♥                     
                      ♥                      
                      ♥         
}


\NewDocumentCommand{\egreg}{O{1}}{\egregBF{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item \texttt{\textbackslash egreg}: \egreg
\item \texttt{\textbackslash egreg[12]}: \egreg[12]
\item \texttt{\textbackslash egreg[-2]}: \egreg[-2]
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that you need to create also a `bxbluf.sty` file to interpret the Brainfuck in the above code (from https://gist.github.com/zr-tex8r/7527995, slighty improved to remove unwanted space):

```
% bxbluf.sty

%% package declaration
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{bxbluf}[2013/11/11 v0.2]

%% preparations
\def\bxbf@pkgname{bxbluf}
\def\bxbf@error{\PackageError\bxbf@pkgname}
\def\bxbf@warn{\PackageWarningNoLine\bxbf@pkgname}
\def\bxbf@err@umbgr{%
  \bxbf@error{Unmatched [ found}\@ehc
}
\def\bxbf@err@umegr{%
  \bxbf@error{Unmatched ] found}\@ehc
}
\def\bxbf@warn@hichr{%
  \bxbf@warn{Non 8-bit character found}%
}
\def\bxbf@warn@ineof{%
  \bxbf@warn{End-of-input reached}%
}
%
\newif\ifbxbf@inloop
\newif\ifbxbf@g@error
\newif\ifbxbf@optok
\providecommand*\bxDebug[1]{}

%--------------------------------------- base

%% variables
\newcount\bxbf@count
\let\bxbf@prcode\@empty

%% \bxbf@op@list : operator list
\def\bxbf@op@list{%
  \do\bxbf@AP\do\bxbf@AV\do\bxbf@ID\do\bxbf@OD\do\bxbf@LP
  \do\bxbf@RP\do\bxbf@RV\do\bxbf@AX\do\bxbf@RX\do\bxbf@SF
}

%% \bxbf@op@frozen
\let\bxbf@op@frozen\relax

%% \bxbf@op@noop
\def\bxbf@op@noop#1{}

%% \bxbf@switch@all@op\CS
\def\bxbf@switch@all@op#1{%
  \let\bxbf@tmpa#1%
  \let\do\bxbf@switch@all@op@do \bxbf@op@list
}
\def\bxbf@switch@all@op@do#1{%
  \let#1\bxbf@tmpa
}

%% \bxbf@modulo{<num>}
\def\bxbf@modulo#1{%
  \@tempcnta=#1\relax \bxbf@count\@tempcnta
  \divide\@tempcnta\bxbf@rbase \multiply\@tempcnta\bxbf@rbase
  \advance\bxbf@count-\@tempcnta
}

%% \bxbf@show
% for debug
\def\bxbf@show{%
  \bxbf@switch@all@op\bxbf@op@frozen
  \bxDebug{prog:\bxbf@prcode}%
}

%--------------------------------------- \scantokens emulation
\ifx\scantokens\@undefined
  % when \scantokens is unavailable
  \newwrite\bxbf@tempfile
  \def\bxbf@tempfilename{\bxbf@pkgname.out}

  \def\bxbf@scantokens#1{%
    \begingroup
      \toks@={#1}%
      \immediate\openout\bxbf@tempfile=\bxbf@tempfilename\relax
      \immediate\write\bxbf@tempfile{\the\toks@}%
      \immediate\closeout\bxbf@tempfile
    \endgroup
    \input{\bxbf@tempfilename}%
  }%

\else
  % uses \scantokens if available
  \let\bxbf@scantokens\scantokens
\fi
%--------------------------------------- LaTeX interface

%% variables
\newcount\bxbf@proc@maxid
\let\bxbf@decl@mode\relax
\let\bxbf@out@verbatim\relax
\let\bxbf@eofval=*

%%<*> \execbf[*] / \execbfwithinput[*] / \procbf[*]
\DeclareRobustCommand*\execbf{%
  \@ifstar{\bxbf@procbf{n}{1}}{\bxbf@procbf{n}{0}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\execbfwithinput{%
  \@ifstar{\bxbf@procbf{i}{1}}{\bxbf@procbf{i}{0}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand*\procbf{%
  \@ifstar{\bxbf@procbf{p}{1}}{\bxbf@procbf{p}{0}}%
}
\def\bxbf@procbf#1#2{%
  \let\bxbf@decl@mode=#1\relax
  \chardef\bxbf@out@verbatim=#2\relax
  \def\bxbf@proc@id{0}%
  \if i\bxbf@decl@mode
    \let\bxbf@tmpa\bxbf@procbf@winput
  \else\if p\bxbf@decl@mode
    \advance\bxbf@proc@maxid\@ne
    \edef\bxbf@proc@id{\the\bxbf@proc@maxid}%
    \let\bxbf@tmpa\bxbf@procbf@wproc
  \else
    \let\bxbf@input\@empty
    \let\bxbf@tmpa\bxbf@procbf@a
  \fi\fi
  \bxbf@tmpa
}
\def\bxbf@procbf@winput#1{% <input>
  \def\bxbf@input{#1}%
  \bxbf@procbf@a
}
\def\bxbf@procbf@wproc#1{% \ProcCS
  \def\bxbf@proc@cs{\noexpand#1}%
  \bxbf@procbf@a
}
\def\bxbf@procbf@a#1{% <program>
  \begingroup
    \global\expandafter\chardef\csname bxbf@OutVerb/\bxbf@proc@id\endcsname
     =\bxbf@out@verbatim
    \bxbf@parse{#1}%
    \bxbf@optimize
    \global\expandafter\let\csname bxbf@PrArray/\bxbf@proc@id\endcsname
     =\bxbf@prcode
  \endgroup
  \ifnum\bxbf@proc@id>0
    \edef\bxbf@tmpa{%
      \gdef\bxbf@proc@cs{\noexpand\bxbf@invoke@proc{\bxbf@proc@id}}%
    }%
    \bxbf@tmpa
  \else % immediate execution
    \bxbf@invoke@proc{\bxbf@proc@id}{\bxbf@input}%
  \fi
}

%% \bxbf@invoke@proc{<id>}{<input>}
\def\bxbf@invoke@proc#1#2{%
  \begingroup
    \bxbf@stringify\bxbf@input{#2}%
    \expandafter\let\expandafter\bxbf@prcode
     \csname bxbf@PrArray/#1\endcsname
    \bxbf@execute
    \xdef\bxbf@g@tmpa{\noexpand\bxbf@process@str
      {\csname bxbf@OutVerb/#1\endcsname}{\bxbf@output}}%
  \endgroup
  \bxbf@g@tmpa
}
\def\bxbf@process@str#1#2{%
  \ifnum#1>\z@
    \begingroup
      \let\bxbfLF\newline \let\bxbfSP\ %
      #2\relax
    \endgroup
  \else
    \begingroup
      \def\bxbfLF{^^J}\def\bxbfSP{ }%
      \xdef\bxbf@g@tmpa{\noexpand\bxbf@scantokens{#2}}%
    \endgroup
    \bxbf@g@tmpa
  \fi
}

%% \bxbf@stringify\CS{<text>}
\def\bxbf@stringify#1#2{%
  \edef\bxbf@tmpa{#2}%
  \expandafter\bxbf@stringify@a\meaning\bxbf@tmpa\bxbf@end#1%
}
\def\bxbf@stringify@a#1->#2\bxbf@end#3{%
  \def#3{#2}%
}

%%<*> \bfeofvalue{<val>}
\newcommand*\bfeofvalue[1]{%
  \def\bxbf@tmpa{#1}%
  \ifx\bxbf@tmpa\bxbf@@star \let\bxbf@eofval=*\relax
  \else\ifx\bxbf@tmpa\bxbf@@bang \let\bxbf@eofval=!\relax
  \else \afterassignment\bxbf@eofvalue@a\bxbf@count=\bxbf@tmpa\bxbf@tn
  \fi\fi
}
\def\bxbf@eofvalue@a#1\bxbf@tn{%
  \def\bxbf@tmpa{#1}%
  \ifx\bxbf@tmpa\@empty
    \bxbf@modulo\bxbf@count
    \ifnum\bxbf@count<\z@ \advance\bxbf@count\bxbf@rbase \fi
    \chardef\bxbf@eofval\bxbf@count
  \else \bxbf@count=\bxbf@tn
  \fi
}
\let\bxbf@tn\relax
\def\bxbf@@star{*}
\def\bxbf@@bang{!}

%--------------------------------------- parse

%% variables
\let\bxbf@block\@empty
\let\bxbf@prev@op\@empty
\let\bxbf@source@rest\@empty
\mathchardef\bxbf@rbase=256
\mathchardef\bxbf@mcmax="7FFF

%% \bxbf@chk
\def\bxbf@chk{\space}

%% \bxbf@parse
\long\def\bxbf@parse#1{%
  \bxbf@switch@all@op\bxbf@op@frozen
  \bxbf@inloopfalse
  \global\bxbf@g@errorfalse
  \edef\bxbf@tmpa{%
    \noexpand\bxbf@parse@block{#1\noexpand\bxbf@chk}}%
  \bxbf@tmpa
  \ifbxbf@g@error \let\bxbf@prcode\@empty
  \else \let\bxbf@prcode\bxbf@block
  \fi
}

%% \bxbf@parse@block
\long\def\bxbf@parse@block#1{%
  \let\bxbf@prev@op\@empty \bxbf@count\z@
  \let\bxbf@block\@empty
  \bxbf@parse@loop@a#1\bxbf@end
}

%% \bxbf@parse@loop
\def\bxbf@parse@loop{%
  \futurelet\bxbf@tmpa\bxbf@parse@loop@a
}
\def\bxbf@parse@loop@a{%
  \ifx\bxbf@tmpa\bgroup \expandafter\bxbf@parse@loop@b
  \else \expandafter\bxbf@parse@loop@ab
  \fi
}
\def\bxbf@parse@loop@ab{%
  \ifx\bxbf@tmpa\@sptoken \expandafter\bxbf@parse@loop@ac
  \else \expandafter\bxbf@parse@loop@c
  \fi
}
\expandafter\def\expandafter\bxbf@parse@loop@ac\space{%
  \bxbf@parse@loop
}
\long\def\bxbf@parse@loop@b#1{%
  \bxbf@parse@loop#1%
}
\long\def\bxbf@parse@loop@c#1{%
  \csname bxbf@p@h/\string#1\endcsname
  \bxbf@parse@loop
}
%% \bxbf@aprse@flush
\def\bxbf@parse@flush{%
  \ifnum\bxbf@count=\z@\else
    \edef\bxbf@block{\bxbf@block\bxbf@prev@op{\the\bxbf@count}}%
  \fi
}
%% \bxbf@aprse@nonaccum
\def\bxbf@parse@nonaccum#1{%
  \bxbf@parse@flush
  \def\bxbf@prev@op{#1}\bxbf@count\@ne
}
%% \bxbf@aprse@accum
\def\bxbf@parse@accum#1#2{%
  \def\bxbf@tmpa{#1}%
  \ifx\bxbf@prev@op\bxbf@tmpa
    \advance\bxbf@count#2%
  \else
    \bxbf@parse@flush
    \bxbf@count#2\def\bxbf@prev@op{#1}
  \fi
}
%% \bxbf@aprse@new@block
\long\def\bxbf@parse@new@block#1#2\bxbf@end{% #1 gobbled
  \bxbf@parse@flush
%\bxDebug{new:\bxbf@block}%
  \begingroup
    \bxbf@inlooptrue
    \bxbf@parse@block{#2}%
    \global\let\bxbf@g@tmpa\bxbf@block
    \global\let\bxbf@g@tmpb\bxbf@source@rest
  \endgroup
  \let\bxbf@source@rest\bxbf@g@tmpb
  \edef\bxbf@block{\bxbf@block\bxbf@LP{\bxbf@g@tmpa}}%
%\bxDebug{back:\bxbf@block}%
  \let\bxbf@prev@op\@empty \bxbf@count\z@
  \expandafter\bxbf@parse@loop\bxbf@source@rest\bxbf@end
}
%% \bxbf@aprse@end@block
\long\def\bxbf@parse@end@block#1#2\bxbf@end{% #1 gobbled
  \bxbf@parse@flush
  \ifbxbf@inloop
    \def\bxbf@source@rest{#2}%
  \else
    \bxbf@err@umegr
    \global\bxbf@g@errortrue
    \let\bxbf@source@rest\@empty
  \fi
}
%% \bxbf@aprse@finale
\long\def\bxbf@parse@finale#1#2\bxbf@end{% #1 gobbled
  \bxbf@parse@flush
  \ifbxbf@inloop
    \bxbf@err@umbgr
    \global\bxbf@g@errortrue
    \def\bxbf@source@rest{\bxbf@chk}%
  \fi
}

%% \bxbf@decl@handler{<token>}{<body>}
\def\bxbf@decl@handler#1{%
  \expandafter\def\csname bxbf@p@h/#1\endcsname
}
\bxbf@decl@handler{+}{\bxbf@parse@accum\bxbf@AV\@ne}
\bxbf@decl@handler{-}{\bxbf@parse@accum\bxbf@AV\m@ne}
\bxbf@decl@handler{>}{\bxbf@parse@accum\bxbf@AP\@ne}
\bxbf@decl@handler{<}{\bxbf@parse@accum\bxbf@AP\m@ne}
\bxbf@decl@handler{,}{\bxbf@parse@nonaccum\bxbf@ID}
\bxbf@decl@handler{.}{\bxbf@parse@nonaccum\bxbf@OD}
\bxbf@decl@handler{[}{\bxbf@parse@new@block}
\bxbf@decl@handler{]}{\bxbf@parse@end@block}
\bxbf@decl@handler{\string\bxbf@chk}{\bxbf@parse@finale}

%--------------------------------------- optimize

%% variables
\let\bxbf@g@block\@empty

%% \bxbf@g@addto@block
\def\bxbf@g@addto@block{\g@addto@macro\bxbf@g@block}

%% \bxbf@opt@addop
\def\bxbf@opt@addop#1#2{%
  \bxbf@g@addto@block{#1#2}%
}

%% \bxbf@intern{<num>}\cont
\edef\bxbf@H{\expandafter\@gobble\string\#}
\def\bxbf@intern#1{%
  \expandafter\bxbf@intern@a\csname\bxbf@H\number#1%
   \expandafter\endcsname\number#1\relax
}
\def\bxbf@intern@a#1#2\relax#3{%
  \ifx#1\relax
    \ifnum#2>\bxbf@mcmax \gdef#1{#2 }%
    \else \global\mathchardef#1=#2\relax
    \fi
  \fi
  #3#1%
}

%% \bxbf@intern@red{<num>}\cont
\def\bxbf@intern@red#1{%
  \bxbf@modulo{#1}%
  \bxbf@intern\bxbf@count
}

%% \bxbf@optimize
\def\bxbf@optimize{%
  \bxbf@switch@opt
  \global\let\bxbf@g@block\@empty
  \bxbf@prcode
  \let\bxbf@prcode\bxbf@g@block
}

%% \bxbf@switch@opt
\def\bxbf@switch@opt{%
  \let\bxbf@AP\bxbf@opt@AP\let\bxbf@AV\bxbf@opt@AV
  \let\bxbf@ID\bxbf@opt@ID\let\bxbf@OD\bxbf@opt@OD
  \let\bxbf@LP\bxbf@opt@LP
  \let\bxbf@RP\bxbf@op@error\let\bxbf@RV\bxbf@op@error
  \let\bxbf@AX\bxbf@opt@AX\let\bxbf@RX\bxbf@op@error
  \let\bxbf@SF\bxbf@op@error
}

%% \bxbf@opt@ID / \bxbf@opt@OD
\def\bxbf@tmpa#1{%
  \def\bxbf@opt@ID##1{\bxbf@g@addto@block{\bxbf@ID#1}}%
  \def\bxbf@opt@OD##1{\bxbf@g@addto@block{\bxbf@OD#1}}%
}
\bxbf@intern{1}\bxbf@tmpa

%% \bxbf@opt@AP
\def\bxbf@opt@AP#1{%
  \ifnum#1<\z@ \bxbf@intern{-#1}{\bxbf@opt@addop\bxbf@RP}%
  \else        \bxbf@intern{+#1}{\bxbf@opt@addop\bxbf@AP}%
  \fi
}
%% \bxbf@opt@AV
\def\bxbf@opt@AV#1{%
  \ifnum#1<\z@ \bxbf@intern@red{-#1}{\bxbf@opt@addop\bxbf@RV}%
  \else        \bxbf@intern@red{+#1}{\bxbf@opt@addop\bxbf@AV}%
  \fi
}
%% \bxbf@opt@AX
\def\bxbf@opt@AX#1{%
  \ifnum#1<\z@ \bxbf@intern@red{-#1}{\bxbf@opt@addop\bxbf@RX}%
  \else        \bxbf@intern@red{+#1}{\bxbf@opt@addop\bxbf@AX}%
  \fi
}

%% \bxbf@opt@check
\def\bxbf@opt@check#1{%
  \bxbf@optokfalse
  \begingroup
    \bxbf@switch@all@op\bxbf@opt@check@ng
    \let\bxbf@AV\bxbf@opt@check@AV
    \let\bxbf@AP\bxbf@opt@check@AP
    \bxbf@count\z@ \@tempcntb\z@
    #1\bxbf@opt@check@fin
  \endgroup
}
\def\bxbf@opt@check@ng#1\bxbf@opt@check@fin{}
\def\bxbf@opt@check@AP#1{%
  \advance\bxbf@count#1\relax
}
\def\bxbf@opt@check@AV#1{%
  \ifnum\bxbf@count=\z@
    \advance\@tempcntb#1\relax
  \fi
}

%% \bxbf@opt@check@fin
\def\bxbf@opt@check@fin{%
  \ifnum\bxbf@count=\z@ \ifnum\@tempcntb=\m@ne
    \aftergroup\bxbf@optoktrue
  \fi\fi
}

%% \bxbf@opt@LP
\def\bxbf@opt@LP#1{%
  \begingroup
    \bxbf@opt@check{#1}%
    \let\bxbf@save@block\bxbf@g@block
    \global\let\bxbf@g@block\@empty
    \ifbxbf@optok
      \let\bxbf@AV\bxbf@AX
    \fi
    #1%
    \expandafter\bxbf@opt@LP@a\expandafter{\bxbf@g@block}%
  \endgroup
}
\def\bxbf@opt@LP@a#1{%
  \let\bxbf@g@block\bxbf@save@block
  \ifbxbf@optok \g@addto@macro\bxbf@g@block{\bxbf@SF{#1}}%
  \else \g@addto@macro\bxbf@g@block{\bxbf@LP{#1}}%
  \fi
}

%% \bxbf@opt@add\CS{<arg>}
\def\bxbf@opt@add#1#2{%
  \g@addto@macro\bxbf@g@block{#1{#2}}%
}

%--------------------------------------- execute
\edef\bxbf@restorecc{\catcode127=\the\catcode127\relax}
\catcode127=12

%% variables
\newcount\bxbf@dptr
\let\bxbf@str@in\@empty
\let\bxbf@str@out\@empty
\chardef\bxbf@zero=0
\chardef\bxbf@lctr=0

%% \bxbf@execute
\def\bxbf@execute{%
%\bxbf@show
  \bxbf@switch@exec
  \global\let\bxbf@str@in\bxbf@input
  \global\let\bxbf@str@out\@empty
  \global\bxbf@g@errorfalse
  \bxbf@dptr\z@
  \bxbf@prcode\bxbf@exec@fin
  \ifbxbf@g@error \let\bxbf@output\@empty
  \else \let\bxbf@output\bxbf@str@out
  \fi
}
\let\bxbf@exec@fin\relax

%% \bxbf@exec@halt
% NB. This is not counted as error.
\def\bxbf@exec@halt#1\bxbf@exec@fin{}

%% \bxbf@swtich@exec
\def\bxbf@switch@exec{%
  \let\bxbf@AP\bxbf@exec@AP\let\bxbf@AV\bxbf@exec@AV
  \let\bxbf@ID\bxbf@exec@ID\let\bxbf@OD\bxbf@exec@OD
  \let\bxbf@LP\bxbf@exec@LP
  \let\bxbf@RP\bxbf@exec@RP\let\bxbf@RV\bxbf@exec@RV
  \let\bxbf@AX\bxbf@exec@AX\let\bxbf@RX\bxbf@exec@RX
  \let\bxbf@SF\bxbf@exec@SF
}

%% bxbf@exec@AP
\def\bxbf@exec@AP#1{%
  \advance\bxbf@dptr#1%
%\bxDebug{AP:\number#1;\number\bxbf@dptr}%
}
%% bxbf@exec@RP
\def\bxbf@exec@RP#1{%
  \advance\bxbf@dptr-#1%
%\bxDebug{RP:\number#1;\number\bxbf@dptr}%
}

%% bxbf@exec@AV
\def\bxbf@exec@AV{%
  \expandafter\bxbf@exec@AV@a\csname ^^?\the\bxbf@dptr\endcsname}
\def\bxbf@exec@AV@a#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\relax \chardef#1#2%
  \else
    \bxbf@count#1\advance\bxbf@count#2%
    \ifnum\bxbf@count<\bxbf@rbase\else \advance\bxbf@count-\bxbf@rbase \fi
    \chardef#1\bxbf@count
  \fi
%\bxDebug{AV:#1:\the#2;\the#1}%
}
%% bxbf@exec@RV
\def\bxbf@exec@RV{%
  \expandafter\bxbf@exec@RV@a\csname ^^?\the\bxbf@dptr\endcsname}
\def\bxbf@exec@RV@a#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\relax \chardef#1\bxbf@zero \fi
  \bxbf@count#1\advance\bxbf@count-#2%
  \ifnum\bxbf@count<\z@ \advance\bxbf@count\bxbf@rbase \fi
  \chardef#1\bxbf@count
%\bxDebug{RV:#1:\the#2;\the#1}%
}

%% bxbf@exec@ID
\def\bxbf@exec@ID{%
  \expandafter\bxbf@exec@ID@a\csname ^^?\the\bxbf@dptr\endcsname}
\def\bxbf@exec@ID@a#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\relax \chardef#1\bxbf@zero \fi
  \bxbf@count#1%
  \bxbf@get@char
  \ifnum\bxbf@count<\z@ \expandafter\bxbf@exec@halt \fi
  \chardef#1\bxbf@count
%\bxDebug{ID:#1;\the#1}%
}

%% bxbf@exec@OD
\def\bxbf@exec@OD{%
  \expandafter\bxbf@exec@OD@a\csname ^^?\the\bxbf@dptr\endcsname}
\def\bxbf@exec@OD@a#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\relax \chardef#1\bxbf@zero\fi%
  \bxbf@count#1%
  \bxbf@put@char%
%\bxDebug{OD:#1;\the#1}%
}

%% bxbf@exec@OD
\def\bxbf@exec@LP{%
  \expandafter\bxbf@exec@LP@a\csname ^^?\the\bxbf@dptr\endcsname}
\def\bxbf@exec@LP@a#1{%
  \ifx#1\relax \chardef#1\bxbf@zero\fi%
%\bxDebug{LP:#1;\the#1}%
  \ifnum#1=\z@ \expandafter\@gobble%
  \else\expandafter\bxbf@exec@LP@b%
  \fi%
}
\def\bxbf@exec@LP@b#1{%
  #1\bxbf@exec@LP{#1}%
}

%% bxbf@exec@SF
\def\bxbf@exec@SF{%
  \expandafter\bxbf@exec@SF@a\csname ^^?\the\bxbf@dptr\endcsname}
\def\bxbf@exec@SF@a#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\relax \chardef#1\bxbf@zero\fi%
  \chardef\bxbf@lctr#1%
  #2%
}

%% bxbf@exec@AX
\def\bxbf@exec@AX{%
  \expandafter\bxbf@exec@AX@a\csname ^^?\the\bxbf@dptr\endcsname}
\def\bxbf@exec@AX@a#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\relax \chardef#1\bxbf@zero\fi
  \bxbf@count#2\multiply\bxbf@count\bxbf@lctr\advance\bxbf@count#1%
  \ifnum\bxbf@count<\bxbf@rbase\else\bxbf@modulo\bxbf@count\fi%
  \chardef#1\bxbf@count%
%\bxDebug{AX:#1:\the#2;\the#1}%
}
%% bxbf@exec@RX
\def\bxbf@exec@RX{%
  \expandafter\bxbf@exec@RX@a\csname ^^?\the\bxbf@dptr\endcsname}
\def\bxbf@exec@RX@a#1#2{%
  \ifx#1\relax%
    \chardef#1\bxbf@zero\fi%
  \bxbf@count#2\multiply\bxbf@count-\bxbf@lctr\advance\bxbf@count#1%
  \ifnum\bxbf@count<\z@ \bxbf@modulo\bxbf@count\fi%
  \ifnum\bxbf@count<\z@ \advance\bxbf@count\bxbf@rbase\fi%
  \chardef#1\bxbf@count%
%\bxDebug{RX:#1:\the#2;\the#1}%
}

\bxbf@restorecc
%--------------------------------------- virtual I/O

%% variables
\chardef\bxbfLF=10
\chardef\bxbfSP=32

%% \bxbf@get@char
\def\bxbf@get@char{%
  \ifx\bxbf@str@in\@empty \bxbf@get@char@mt%
  \else%
    \expandafter\bxbf@get@char@a\bxbf@str@in\bxbf@end%
  \fi%
}
\def\bxbf@get@char@a{%
  % don't discard spaces!
  \futurelet\bxbf@tmpa\bxbf@get@char@b%
}
\def\bxbf@get@char@b{%
  \ifx\bxbf@tmpa\@sptoken%
    \expandafter\bxbf@get@char@d%
  \else%
    \expandafter\bxbf@get@char@c%
  \fi%
}
\def\bxbf@get@char@c#1#2\bxbf@end{%
  \bxbf@count`#1\relax \gdef\bxbf@str@in{#2}%
  \ifnum\bxbf@count>\@cclv%
    \expandafter\bxbf@invalid@char%
  \fi
}
\def\bxbf@get@char@d{%
  \afterassignment\bxbf@get@char@e \let\bxbf@tmpa=%
}
\def\bxbf@get@char@e#1\bxbf@end{%
  \bxbf@count\bxbfSP \gdef\bxbf@str@in{#1}%
}
\def\bxbf@invalid@char{%
  \bxbf@warn@hichr%
  \bxbf@count\z@% non 8-bit char is replaced by zero
}
\def\bxbf@get@char@mt{%
  \ifx!\bxbf@eofval%
    \bxbf@warn@ineof%
    \bxbf@count\m@ne%
  \else\ifx*\bxbf@eofval\else%
    \bxbf@count\bxbf@eofval%
  \fi\fi%
}

%% \bxbf@put@char
\def\bxbf@put@char{%
  \lccode`!=\bxbf@count%
  \lowercase{%
    \xdef\bxbf@str@out{\bxbf@str@out%
      \ifnum\bxbf@count=\bxbfLF \bxbfLF%
      \else\ifnum\bxbf@count=\bxbfSP \bxbfSP%
      \else !\fi\fi}%
  }%
%\bxDebug{OUT:\bxbf@str@out:\the\bxbf@count}%
}

%--------------------------------------- all done
\endinput
%% EOF
```

Comment: Excellent ridiculous solution! You are right about the minus sign, that is the logical behaviour, but I only realized that after the answers had started coming in, so we're stuck with the original question.

Comment: This is worth another bounty!

Comment: @egreg Ahah thanks, I'm happy to see that you like it, I would never have expected to ever receive a bounty from you ^^ (the fact that you have never asked a single question does not help! https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg?tab=questions)

Comment: Yes, @egreg is usually the one who *receives* bounties. Still, I hope that some day, just for fun, he will ask some question in here.

Answer (score 17):

What we can do in OpTeX:

```
\optdef\wipet[1]{\if i\the\opt ${\rm wi}+i{\rm pet}$%
   \else
      \tmpnum=\the\opt\relax
      \ifnum\tmpnum<0 \fornum 1..-\tmpnum \do{pet}\fi
      wi%
      \ifnum\tmpnum>0 \fornum 1..\tmpnum \do{pet}\fi
   \fi
}

\wipet\ should produce ``wipet''

\wipet[0]\ should produce ``wi''

\wipet[1]\ should produce ``wipet''

\wipet[2]\ should produce ``wipetpet''

\wipet[5]\ should produce ``wipetpetpetpetpet''

\wipet[-1]\ should produce ``petwi''

\wipet[-2]\ should produce ``petpetwi''

\wipet[i]\ perhaps "${\rm wi} + i{\rm pet}$"

\bye
```

Comment: So, wipet is a pet, and wipetpet is like wipet’s pet?

Comment: Looking forward to @DavidCarlisle making a solution with a command `\carlisle` such that `\carlisle[2]` produces “carlislisle” or something.

Comment: @Gaussler true artists can not be mechanically copied in that way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, then produce your own original art instead. Come up with a solution on the level of your “n’th day of Christmas” masterpiece.

Comment: @Gaussler I already contributed [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/681433/1090) this month, and you expect more?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Expect? Of course not. But I’m sure egreg would be happy.  (And good work by the way!)

Answer (score 15):

Just for comparison, here is a version in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) (with apologies for being so far from the brief, apart from the "ridiculous" bit).

[image]

Compile with `lualatex`.  (Here be dragons...)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
picture payload; 
payload = textext("$\vcenter{\hbox{egreg}}\;$");
payload := payload scaled (1/abs(lrcorner payload - llcorner payload));
vardef dragon(expr level, a, b, r) = 
    if level = 0:
        draw a--b withcolor 3/4;
        draw payload zscaled (b-a) shifted a;
    else:
        save p; pair p;
        p = 0.7071067811865476[a, b] rotatedabout(a, r); 
        
        dragon(level-1, a, p, +abs(r));
        dragon(level-1, p, b, -abs(r)); 
    fi
enddef;
beginfig(1);
        dragon(11, origin, 600 right, 45); 
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @egreg I hope a "thank you" comment is allowed.  Or perhaps I should say "Grazie mille!"

Answer (score 14):

I like recursions:

```
\documentclass{article}

\NewDocumentCommand\egreg{O{1}}{%
  \ifnum #1>0 eg\reg{#1}\else\ifnum #1<0 \reg{-#1}\fi eg\fi
}
\newcommand*{\reg}[1]{%
  \ifnum #1>0 \-reg\reg{\numexpr #1-1\relax}\fi
}

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\egreg{}  should produce ``egreg"

\egreg[0] should produce ``eg"

\egreg[1] should produce ``egreg"

\egreg[2] should produce ``egregreg"

\egreg[5] should produce ``egregregregregreg"

\medskip
Perhaps we might also want to allow negative values:

\egreg[-1] should produce ``regeg"

\egreg[-2] should produce ``regregeg"

\medskip
And also with hyphenation: \egreg[100]

\end{document}
```

Yes, handling of complex values is missing.

Comment: Good, in case I want to write “egregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregregreg”.

Comment: In general, isn’t it safer to use `''` (two apostrophes) instead of `"` (quotation mark), especially since `babel` has a tendency to make the latter active?

Comment: @Gaussler Generally it would be safer *and* better to use `csquotes`. But IMHO the question was not about safer and better solutions. ;-) (But honestly, I was simply too lazy to replace all the quotes.)

Answer (score 10):

The following, LuaLaTeX-based solution probably won't qualify as being *completely ridiculous*, since it doesn't actually employ any loop-type control structures; it is left as an exercise to the motivated reader to replace Lua's `string.rep` function with a suitable `for`, `while`, or `repeat .. until` loop. Also, to keep @egreg's blood pressure from spiking up, I use `\mathrm` instead of `\text` directives...

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
```

```lua
function egreg ( n )
  if n=="" then
    tex.sprint ("egreg")
  elseif n=="i" then
    tex.sprint ( "\\ensuremath{\\mathrm{eg}+i\\mathrm{reg}}" )
  else
    n = tonumber ( n )
    if n<0 then
      tex.sprint (        string.rep ( "reg",-n) .. "eg" )
    else
      tex.sprint ( "e" .. string.rep ( "gre", n) .. "g" )
    end
  end
end
```

```tex
\end{luacode*}
%% LaTeX-side code:
\newcommand\egreg[1][]{\directlua{egreg("#1")}}

\begin{document}

\obeylines % just for this example
\egreg 
\egreg[0] 
\egreg[1] 
\egreg[5] 
\egreg[-1] 
\egreg[-2]
\egreg[i] 

\end{document}
```

Comment: What about mixed expressions like `3+2i`? 

Comment: @Gaussler - Should `\egreg[3+2i]` evaluate to `\egreg[3]+i\egreg[2]`? Or maybe its complex conjugate? :-)

Comment: Probably. But your guess is as good as mine. 

Comment: @Gaussler - Upon reflection, I've decided to leave the job of creating a complex-valued `\egreg` macro as an extra-credit assignment to readers...

Answer (score 4):

An expl3 abstraction, to a certain approximation:

[image: egreg]

[image: carlisle]

Besides being ridiculous in coding, style, design, purpose, outcome, background colour, submission time, some imaginable items, and other things, what this shows is that: egreg is, simultaneously, equivalent to, and not equivalent to, carlisle. Mirabile dictu!

And utterly ridiculous!!

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{NotoSerif}
\pagecolor{blue!5}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:c {c_texta_tl}
\tl_set:cn 
    {c_texta_tl}
    { ~ produces ~}


\tl_new:N \l_tmpc_tl





\tl_new:N \l_egreg_oarg_tl
\newcommand{\egregnodelength}{2}
\int_new:N \l_enl_loop_int



%------------------------------------------------------------------

\cs_new:Npn \setegreg:n #1 
{ 
\exp_args:Nc 
\NewDocumentCommand { #1 } { o } {

    \tl_if_novalue:nTF { ##1 }
        { 
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 0 }
            }
        {
            \tl_set:Nn \l_egreg_oarg_tl { ##1 }
            \tl_if_eq:NnTF \l_egreg_oarg_tl { i } { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 9999 }    }
            {\tl_if_eq:NnTF \l_egreg_oarg_tl { zzz } { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 9998 }     }
            {\tl_if_eq:NnTF \l_egreg_oarg_tl { egreg } { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 9997 }   }
                { 
                    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { ##1 }
                }
            }}
            }
            
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #1 } %***********
%   \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl 

    \tl_if_exist:cF { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
        {%%%%%%%%%%%
            \tl_new:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
            }
    \tl_if_exist:cF { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
        {
            \tl_new:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
            }

    \seq_set_split:NnV  \l_tmpa_seq {  } { \l_tmpa_tl } 
%   \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
%   \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
    

    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpb_tl
    \int_set:Nn \l_enl_loop_int { 0 }
    \int_do_until:nNnn { \l_enl_loop_int } = { \egregnodelength } 
    {
    
    \seq_pop_left:NN
        \l_tmpa_seq
        \l_tmpc_tl 
    \tl_put_right:NV
        \l_tmpb_tl
        \l_tmpc_tl      
        
        \int_incr:N \l_enl_loop_int
    }

    \tl_gset_eq:cN { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl } \l_tmpb_tl 

    \tl_gset:cn 
        { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl } 
        { \seq_use:Nnnn
            \l_tmpa_seq
            {}{}{}
         }



        \int_case:nnTF
            { \l_tmpa_int }
            {
                { 9999 } { 
                        \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
                        $ + i $
                        \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                             }
                { 9998 } { 
                            \showegreg{#1}
                             }
                { 9997 } { 
        \textcolor{blue}{
        \texttt{
        \textbackslash
        #1[#1]
        }}
        \tl_use:N \c_texta_tl 
        ``carlisle''.
                             }
            }
            {}{ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \int_case:nnTF
            { \int_sign:n { \l_tmpa_int } }
            {
                { 0 } {
%                       \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
%                       \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }

                            \int_until_do:nNnn
                                { \l_tmpb_int }
                                =
                                { \c_zero_int }
                                {
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                                    \int_decr:N \l_tmpb_int
                                }
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
                            \int_until_do:nNnn
                                { \l_tmpa_int }
                                =
                                { \c_zero_int }
                                {
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                                    \int_decr:N \l_tmpa_int
                                }
                                
                            \tl_if_novalue:nT { ##1 }
                                { 
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                                }
                        }
                { -1 } {
                            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { \int_abs:n { \l_tmpa_int } }
                            \int_until_do:nNnn
                                { \l_tmpb_int }
                                =
                                { \c_zero_int }
                                {
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                                    \int_decr:N \l_tmpb_int
                                }
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
                        }
                { 1 } {
                            \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
                            \int_until_do:nNnn
                                { \l_tmpa_int }
                                =
                                { \c_zero_int }
                                {
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                                    \int_decr:N \l_tmpa_int
                                }
                        }
            }
            {}{}            

        } %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    } % end-NDC


}


%------------------------------------------------------------------

\NewDocumentCommand{\makeegreg} { m } {
\setegreg:n  { #1 }
}

%------------------------------------------------------------------

\NewDocumentCommand { \egregX } { o } {

    \tl_if_novalue:nTF { #1 }
        { 
            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 0 }
            }
        {
            \tl_set:Nn \l_egreg_oarg_tl { #1 }
            \tl_if_eq:NnTF \l_egreg_oarg_tl { i } { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 9999 }    }
            {\tl_if_eq:NnTF \l_egreg_oarg_tl { zzz } { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 9998 }     }
            {\tl_if_eq:NnTF \l_egreg_oarg_tl { egreg } { \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { 9997 }   }
                { 
                    \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { #1 }
                }
            }}
            }
            
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { egreg } %***********
%   \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl 

    \tl_if_exist:cF { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
        {%%%%%%%%%%%
            \tl_new:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
            }
    \tl_if_exist:cF { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
        {
            \tl_new:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
            }

    \seq_set_split:NnV  \l_tmpa_seq {  } { \l_tmpa_tl } 
%   \tl_show:N \l_tmpa_tl
%   \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
    

    \tl_clear:N \l_tmpb_tl
    \int_set:Nn \l_enl_loop_int { 0 }
    \int_do_until:nNnn { \l_enl_loop_int } > { \egregnodelength } 
    {
    
    \seq_pop_left:NN
        \l_tmpa_seq
        \l_tmpc_tl 
    \tl_put_right:NV
        \l_tmpb_tl
        \l_tmpc_tl      
        
        \int_incr:N \l_enl_loop_int
    }


    \tl_gset_eq:cN { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl } \l_tmpb_tl 

    \tl_gset:cn 
        { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl } 
        { \seq_use:Nnnn
            \l_tmpa_seq
            {}{}{}
         }



        \int_case:nnTF
            { \l_tmpa_int }
            {
                { 9999 } { 
                        \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
                        $ + i $
                        \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                             }
                { 9998 } { 
                            \showegreg{egreg}
                             }
                { 9997 } { 
        \textcolor{blue}{
        \texttt{
        \textbackslash
        egreg[egreg]
        }}
        \tl_use:N \c_texta_tl 
        ``carlisle''.
                             }
            }
            {}{ %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        \int_case:nnTF
            { \int_sign:n { \l_tmpa_int } }
            {
                { 0 } {
%                       \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
%                       \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }

                            \int_until_do:nNnn
                                { \l_tmpb_int }
                                =
                                { \c_zero_int }
                                {
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                                    \int_decr:N \l_tmpb_int
                                }
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
                            \int_until_do:nNnn
                                { \l_tmpa_int }
                                =
                                { \c_zero_int }
                                {
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                                    \int_decr:N \l_tmpa_int
                                }
                                
                            \tl_if_novalue:nT { #1 }
                                { 
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                                }
                        }
                { -1 } {
                            \int_set:Nn \l_tmpb_int { \int_abs:n { \l_tmpa_int } }
                            \int_until_do:nNnn
                                { \l_tmpb_int }
                                =
                                { \c_zero_int }
                                {
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                                    \int_decr:N \l_tmpb_int
                                }
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
                        }
                { 1 } {
                            \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _head_tl }
                            \int_until_do:nNnn
                                { \l_tmpa_int }
                                =
                                { \c_zero_int }
                                {
                                    \tl_use:c { g_ \l_tmpa_tl _tail_tl }
                                    \int_decr:N \l_tmpa_int
                                }
                        }
            }
            {}{}            

        } %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    } % end-NDC


%------------------------------------------------------------------


\NewDocumentCommand { \showegreg } { m o } {

\tl_if_novalue:nTF { #2 }
{
\tl_set:Nn 
    \l_tmpa_tl
    {
        \textcolor{blue}{
        \texttt{
        \textbackslash
        #1
        }}
        \tl_use:N \c_texta_tl 
        ``\use:c {#1}''.
    }
}   
{
\tl_set:Nn 
    \l_tmpa_tl
    {
        \textcolor{blue}{
        \texttt{
        \textbackslash
        #1[#2]
        }}
        \tl_use:N \c_texta_tl 
        ``\use:c {#1}[#2]''.
    }
}   
\tl_use:N 
    \l_tmpa_tl
}



\NewDocumentCommand { \showegregall } { m } {

\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1} ~

\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1}[0]

\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1}[1]

\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1}[-1]

\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1}[-5]

\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1}[i]

\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1}[zzz]

\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1}[egreg]

\renewcommand{\egregnodelength}{3}
\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1}[-5]


\renewcommand{\egregnodelength}{1}
\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1}[-5]

\renewcommand{\egregnodelength}{2}
\tex_par:D
\showegreg{#1}[-5]

}





\ExplSyntaxOff




\begin{document}

\makeegreg{egreg}
\egreg
\showegregall{egreg}

\newpage
\makeegreg{carlisle}
\carlisle

\showegregall{carlisle}
%
%\showegreg{carlisle}[4]
%
%\showegreg{carlisle}[i]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Bounty in progress!

Comment: The submission time is not necessarily ridiculous. With the right definition, I’m sure that yesterday can be regarded as April i.

Answer (score 3):

Nobody remember `multido`?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parindent0pt\parskip0pt
\newcommand\egreg[1][1]{%
\IfInteger{#1}{%
\ifnum #1<0 \multido{}{#1}{\reflectbox{reg}}\reflectbox{eg}\else
\ifnum #1>0 
{\bfseries{eg}\multido{}{#1}{reg}}\par
\else  eg\par\fi\fi}{{eg\emph{reg}}\par}}
\centering
\begin{document}
\sffamily
\multido{}{9}{\egreg[i]}  
\egreg [-4] \egreg [4]
\egreg [-3] \egreg [3]
\egreg [-2] \egreg [2]
\egreg[-1] \egreg [1]
\egreg[0]
\huge \egreg 
\end{document}
```